# setInterval into Infinity loops

Tags: javascript, for-loop, setinterval

Her is my new code with setinternal of 4 images. However, I am trying to have an infinite loops of the same images. Can you help me to understands how to create a setInterval loop.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var OpenWindow = window.open("","","top=100, left=400,resizable=yes,height=550,width=550,menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes");

    var imgURLS = ['Oculus.jpg', 'future-vr.jpg', 'morpheus.jpg', 'samsungvr.jpg'];
    var imgIndex = 0;

    var timer = setInterval(function() {
            for (var imgIndex = 0; j < imgURLS.length; j++)
            {
             for (var imgIndex = 0; i < imgURLS.length; i++)
             {
            clearInterval(timer);
        } else {
OpenWindow.document.write("<div class='css-slideshow'>");
OpenWindow.document.write("<figure>");
OpenWindow.document.write('<img src ="' + imgURLS[imgIndex++] +  '">');
OpenWindow.document.write("</figure>");
OpenWindow.document.write("</div>");
        }
    }, 3000);

    </script>
```

I just figure out how to make longer loops. However, my images are showing  broke?

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var OpenWindow = window.open("","","top=100, left=400,resizable=yes,height=550,width=550,menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes");

    var imgURLS = ['Oculus.jpg', 'future-vr.jpg', 'morpheus.jpg', 'samsungvr.jpg'];
    var imgIndex = 0;

    var i = setInterval(function() {
            imgIndex++;
    if(imgIndex === 20) {
        clearInterval(i);
        } else {
OpenWindow.document.write("<div class='images-1'>");
OpenWindow.document.write('<img src ="' + imgURLS.length +  '">');
OpenWindow.document.write("</div>");
        }
    }, 3000);
    </script>
```

I figure out why the image were broke. it was missing this `imgURLS[imgIndex]`

new code is:

```
OpenWindow.document.write('<img src ="' + imgURLS[imgIndex] +  '">');
OpenWindow.document.write('<img src ="' + imgURLS.length +  '">');
```

Comment: I see an `else` with no `if` - infinite loops require infinite resources and infinite time, are you sure you want to go there?

Comment: @JaromandaX4 I think that is the only way to make the image loops. None stop from image 1 to 4?sorry for`else`.It is not supposed to be there.

Comment: you want to change the image in the new window every 3 seconds - forever looping through 4 images - is that correct?

Comment: Tried using `css` animation ?

Comment: @JaomandaX Yes! Can you? since guest271314 suggested to do an CSS animation?

Comment: This answer could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835126/javascript-infinitely-looping-slideshow-with-delays/5835336#5835336

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way with `setTimeout`.

1) Add an `id` to your containing `div` and target it.

```
var image = document.querySelector('#css-slideshow img');
```

2) Use `setTimeout` to repeatedly call the same loop function with increments of `count`. If `count` equals the length of the images array, set it to zero.

```
function carousel() {
  var timer, count = 0;
  var loop = function loop(count) {
    if (count === imgURLS.length) count = 0;
    image.src = imgURLS[count];
    timer = setTimeout(loop, 2000, ++count);
  }
  loop(count);
}

carousel();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xjp6vjfk/12/)

Comment: thanks! it is working well, but i need to have it into a `window.open` basically. Maybe i can try to see how to add some of your codes into mine and this can improve the one have at the moment. Any suggestion concerning my codes?

Comment: Do this on the image var, add OpenWindow.document.querySelector bit