# Array element animate[fade in and out ] continous using setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I have an array of numbers and currentValue array values dynamically changes if same values animate *( fade-in and fade-out )* the Tooltipclass elements but its not working.
check currentValue array then get the same value index if i get index 0 and 3 are same value and animate the Tooltipclass index 0 and 3 element.
***JS:***

```
eg: var currentValue = [3,5,3];
    // index 0 and 2 same values 

    var Tooltipclass = ['.helpertool_1','.helpertool_2','.helpertool_3'];
    // class index 0 and 2 ll animate
```

***JS:***

```
function getSamevalue(values){
    var currentValue = [3,5,3]; //[values] dynamically values ll change
    var Tooltipclass = ['.helpertool_1','.helpertool_2','.helpertool_3'];
        $.each(Tooltipclass, function(i, val) {
              setTimeout(function() {
                  $(Tooltipclass[i]).fadeOut("slow", function() {
                      $(this).fadeIn("slow");
                  });
              }, i * 3000);
         });
}

getSamevalue(values);
```

***CSS:***

```
.tooltip{ background: red;position:absolute; width:50px; height:20px; }
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://fiddle.jshell.net/friendz/42y08384/1/)

Comment: 1. In your JSFiddle include jQuery 2. You need to pass values too the parameter since values is not defined. Then some people can help.

Comment: Something like this https://fiddle.jshell.net/42y08384/4/ ??

Comment: Its not continuous looping and  currentValue = [3,5,3]  index 0 and 2 value only same so we can animate .helpertool_1 and .helpertool_3

Comment: you should use `setInterval` for infinite looping

Comment: please refer http://jsfiddle.net/Q6kp3/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Infinite Loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835126/javascript-infinite-loop)

Comment: @RRR its working fine but sometimes 2 or 3 list appear at same time. Then how to compare currentValue = [3,5,3]; and Tooltipclass = ['.helpertool_1','.helpertool_2','.helpertool_3'];