# JavaScript: I need a continuous loop that won't kill the browser or block the page

Tags: javascript, loops, carousel, continuous

I have a carousel plugin I've created and I need a way to have it run a function that moves the image to the side and brings in the next image. I have this working with navigation arrows but I want to implement a way for it to do this on its own.

I'm having trouble finding information on this as Google is bloated with everyone's carousel libraries.

Basically, I just need something like:

```
window.setTimeout(() => {
  // do something
}, 1000);
```

But it needs to run over and over unless a particular event is triggered. My first thought was a `while` loop but that would have been disastrous.

I don't have much to show but currently, this is the code:

```
  let mouseIsOver = false;

  inner.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    mouseIsOver = true;

    console.log(mouseIsOver);
  });

  inner.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    mouseIsOver = false;

    console.log(mouseIsOver);
  });
```

Comment: requestAnimationFrame

Comment: You could use `window.setInterval(() => {}, 1000);` to make it continuous.

Comment: setInterval and store its handle for cancellation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Infinite Loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835126/javascript-infinite-loop)

Comment: Also, you could call setTimeout again from the function being called, and than check if your event has triggered before continuing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) method which repeatedly calls a function. And then call `clearInterval` to stop it.

```js
const inner = document.getElementById('inner');
const pages = ['mediumspringgreen', 'coral', 'cyan', 'moccasin'];
let interval = start();
let i = 0;

function start() {
    return setInterval(() => inner.style.background = pages[i++ % 4], 3000);
}

inner.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  clearInterval(interval);
  console.log('pause');
});

inner.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  interval = start();
  console.log('continue');
});
```

```css
#inner { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: cyan }
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 1.5em !important; }
```

```html
<div id=inner></div>
```

Comment: You need to use requestAnimationFrame because that allows the browser to choose when the next available rendering frame is available.

Comment: @Geuis You're not right. `requestAnimationFrame` is designed to animate elements (for example, repaint something 60 times per second). And `setInterval` executes some action at a fixed rate (which is what OP asks for). Technically, `setInterval` _can_ be used to perform animation and `requestAnimationFrame` _can_ be used to execute some action at a fixed rate, but both of these approaches are bad practice.

Comment: I'm interpreting his question as needing to run the same function over and over to change a CSS property. You shouldn't do this inside of a setTimeout because it prevents the browser from choosing the most efficient time to repaint.

Comment: Thanks , setInterval(() => inner.style.background = pages[i++ % 4], 3000); this snippet helped me resolve my Question.

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, I just need something like:
>
> ```
> window.setTimeout(() => {
>   // do something
> }, 1000);
> ```
>
> But it needs to run over and over unless a particular event is
>   triggered.

Have you considered [`window.setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)?

> The `setInterval()` method... repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call. It returns an interval ID which uniquely identifies the interval, so you can remove it later by calling `clearInterval()`.

Considering your use case, here's one possible solution:

```
  let mouseIsOver = false;

  // start a timer that runs goToNextImage() every 1000 ms and
  // stores its ID so it can be cancelled on mouseenter
  let goToNextImageTimer = window.setInterval(goToNextImage, 1000);

  inner.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    mouseIsOver = true;

    console.log(mouseIsOver);

    if (goToNextImageTimer !== null) {
      // stop interval timer if running
      window.clearInterval(goToNextImageTimer);
    }
  });

  inner.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    mouseIsOver = false;

    console.log(mouseIsOver);

    if (goToNextImageTimer === null) {
      // start interval timer if not running
      goToNextImageTimer = window.setInterval(goToNextImage, 1000);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to look at requestAnimationFrame. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: I wouldn't use `requestAnimationFrame` for a use case like this because it looks like the question asker does not need to (quoting the MDN article) "update an animation before the next repaint," but rather call it every second or so. `setInterval` looks more suited to this use case. If the function being called were actually animating the carousel every frame, then I would recommend `requestAnimationFrame` for that (potentially started by a `setInterval`).

Comment: @ArkaneMoose Any time you are doing any kind of animation with js in the DOM, you need to use requestAnimationFrame. It was specifically designed for this problem space.

Comment: Please care to provide an example of executing some action every 3 seconds using `requestAnimationFrame`. I'm just curious how you implement it. I'm not going to downvote you by the way.