# Chrome launched from service freeze with ^@^@^@^@ output

Tags: google-chrome

We are running a Chrome from a linux service and sometimes the instance of chrome freeze (and all the computer too) unexpectedly with the following error :

```
May 27 21:57:51 Q190N-prototype google-chrome[24703]: [24703:24703:0527/215751.950576:INFO:CONSOLE(342)] "nextVideo()", source: http://192.168.22.16/animatic/static/js/player/index.js?ver=1558013787 (342)
May 27 21:57:51 Q190N-prototype google-chrome[24703]: [24703:24703:0527/215751.952062:INFO:CONSOLE(342)] "nextVideo()", source: http://192.168.22.16/animatic/static/js/player/index.js?ver=1558013787 (342)
May 27 21:58:03 Q190N-prototype google-chrome[24703]: [24703:24703:0527/215803.050265:INFO:CONSOLE(342)] "nextVideo()", source: http://192.168.22.16/animatic/static/js/player/index.js?ver=1558013787 (342)
May 27 21:58:03 Q190N-prototype google-chrome[24703]: [24703:24703:0527/215803.051856:INFO:CONSOLE(342)] "nextVideo()", source: http://192.168.22.16/animatic/static/js/player/index.js?ver=1558013787 (342)
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@May 28 10:33:49 Q190N
-prototype lvm[213]: 2 logical volume(s) in volume group "debian-vg" monitored
May 28 10:33:49 Q190N-prototype keyboard-setup.sh[211]: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier /tmp/tmpkbd.k7WSzt
```

Any idea in order to solve this problem is welcome...

Comment: Do you have any looping code anywhere in your extension atall?

Comment: And can you also verify that the video that is being played (I assume one is being played from the 'nextVideo()' string) is fully playable by other means and is not corrupted. Can you get it consistently by attempting to play a certain video?

Comment: EDIT: forgive me for calling it an extension in my first comment, i meant in the 'animatic/static/js/player/index.js' script (or any other scripts that are used by that script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a problem on **index.js** or **another imported script**.

There are a list of possibilities, but most times freeze is caused by `while(true)` or long loops.

If this is the problem, try:

1. You can break the calculation up into pieces and do a piece at a time on a 
   `setTimeout()`. On each `setTimeout()` call, the browser will be free to serve other 
   events and will keep the page alive and responive. When you finish the last piece of the calculation, you can then carry out the result.
2. You can run the calculation in the background using a webworker in modern browsers. When the calcuation is done in the webworker, it sends a message back to the main thread and you can then update the DOM with the result.

This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49961782/11578778

I hope this helps!

Brhaka

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a buffer overflow to me, `Q190N-prototype keyboard-setup.sh` is the linux keyboard map and stores the map file in /tmp.
`/tmp/tmpkbd.k7WSz` seems like the map file for keyboard binding.

`^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@` is definitely garbage from memory. Now the question is what are how is your player jumping to this address. Is it waiting for some keyboard input at some point of time while playing media. May be at the end when to play next or something.

Its either a permission or file not found issue
**try it with *`sudo`* once and see if you can reproduce the error**