# Differences between types of Javascript function declarations

Tags: javascript

While reading about IronJS, I can across the article here http://ironjs.wordpress.com/

In it is the following:

***Context sensitive function keyword**

In case you didn’t know, these two functions are not identical:

```
(function bar() { })  

function foo() { }
```

*Finding out the difference I’ll leave as an exercise to the reader.*

Can some explain the difference here?

Comment: One is a **function declaration** and the other is a **named function expression**. *Finding out which is which I'll leave as an exercise to the reader.* ;)

Comment: If the reader reads kangax on NFE (named function expressions) they *should* be enlightened. http://kangax.github.com/nfe/

Comment: @SeanVieira Thanks for the link, look like a good article!

Comment: related: [Explain JavaScript's anonymous function syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1634268/1048572) and [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1048572)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am guessing the difference is that the first one is not visible to the global scope and the latter is visible globally.

Comment: This is correct, but that form isn't very useful. More useful is `(function(){}())` or `(function(){})()` which makes the function invisible to the global scope, but runs immediately.

Comment: But why? (I know but you probably should explain it.)

Answer (score 9):

```
function foo() { }
```

Creates a function

```
(function foo(){ })
```

Returns a function object. You can also use:

```
(function foo(){ })(bar)
```

And make an anonymous function. (Note that the `(bar)` means that within that function `this` refers to the `bar` instance.)

Check out [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1140089/298053) for more information.

Comment: Did you mean *immediate* or *self-invoking* function in the end? Although you execute it immediately, it has still a name, so it is not anonymous. `(function(){ })` or `(function(){ })(bar)` would be.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on @Amir's answer:

```
js>(function bar() {})(3)
js>bar
console:1       ReferenceError: bar is not defined
js>function foo() {}
js>foo
function foo() {
}
```

(code executed in [jsdb](http://www.jsdb.org/))

These are named functions, and if you don't put parentheses around the function definition, they become part of the local scope. `function foo() {}` becomes available for use later, but `bar` does not.

As a third example:

```
var x = function baz() {};
```

If you run this:

```
js>var x = function baz() {}
js>baz
console:1       ReferenceError: baz is not defined
```

You'll note that it's the similar case as `(function baz(){})(3)`.

The case of

```
function foo() {}
```

is special, the Javascript interpreter sees that form and says, "Oh, you're trying to define a function named "foo" in the local scope."

As for why a named function is useful even if it doesn't get defined in the local scope -- the named function *is* visible from the scope of the function itself:

```
js>var x = function fact(n) { return n*((n < 2) ? 1 : fact(n-1)); }
js>x(3)
6
js>fact
console:1       ReferenceError: fact is not defined
```

Here we have a factorial function named "fact", but the name "fact" is only visible inside the scope of the function itself.

Comment: +1 for so much examples. Named function expressions should be avoided anyway. If I remember correctly it caused some weird behaviour in older IE versions (namely creating *two* versions of the same functions with two different names).

Answer (score 2):

The first function is a named anonymous function (yeah). The expression evaluates to a `Function`. The second one defines a named function and returns `undefined`.