# How do you show the current time on a web page?

Tags: html, time, web, clock

I want to show the current time on a website I am making for class, but I cannot find a way to do so. Is their a way to show real time in code? and if so, how do you do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display system time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787374/how-to-display-system-time)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can accomplish this fairly easily by first creating an element:

```
<span id="clock"></span>
```

And then getting a reference to that element:

```
var clockElement = document.getElementById( "clock" );
```

Next we'll need a function that will update the contents with the time:

```
function updateClock ( clock ) {
    clock.innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

Lastly, we'll want to make sure we're calling this every second to keep the clock up to date:

```
setInterval(function () {
    updateClock( clockElement );
}, 1000);
```

So when we put it all together it looks like this:

```
(function () {

  var clockElement = document.getElementById( "clock" );

  function updateClock ( clock ) {
    clock.innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
  }

  setInterval(function () {
      updateClock( clockElement );
  }, 1000);

}());
```

Comment: Such an elegant way of doing. I know this is an old post. But I am just curious what is that special `(function () {}());` structure? I am not an expert in Javascript and jQuery

Comment: The function structure is called IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). It's a function that calls itself. MDN has a helpful overview - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE