# How to display current time in realtime with flask and moment.js?

Tags: python, flask, momentjs

I want to display the current time on a webpage with Flask.
At the moment I have this code which displays the current time but does not update unless the user explicitly refresh the page.

```
<div id="datetime">
    <h2>{{ moment().format('HH:mm', refresh=True)}}</h2>
    <h2>{{ moment().format('ddd DD/MM/YY', refresh=True) }}</h2>
</div>
```

I am aware that the refresh option only re-renders the time and does not update it.
How can I make it that the time stays up-to-date?

Comment: You'll need to write JavaScript to update that string every second or so.

Comment: Do you want the **server** time or the **client** (browser) time?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Actually, either could work. This is going to run on a Raspberry Pi. The Pi will run a flask app and display it on a monitor(as a sort of kiosk). So essentially client and server are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to write this would be going the JavaScript route as @tyteen4a03 said. Take a look at this question for help: [How do you show the current time on a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415178/how-do-you-show-the-current-time-on-a-web-page)

Like you mentioned in the question, the only Flask/moment way to achieve something similar is using the Auto-refresh option.