# I'm try to get my time to display from javascript and continue to count up ( ie 2:30:45 then 2:30:46) and I'm having a hard time here' my current code

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time

```js
var d = new Date();
var time = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + d.getDate() + " " + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes();
document.getElementById("currentDay").innerHTML = time;
```

Comment: Specifically look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51738434/4604701) on the above question.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting your code in an interval. That way, it will be called every second.

```
setInterval(() => {

    //Your code here

},1000);
```