# Convert jQuery to Prototype (small code)?

Tags: prototypejs, jquery

I have a site that runs n Vivvo CMS. It is based mainly on Prototype. I would like to implement on site this function, but is jQuery based. Allthough i use jQuery.noconflict, it still doesn't run.

I would like to convert the code below from jQuery to Prototype, can anyone help me?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  // get the height of #wrap
  var h = $('#wrap').height();
  var y = $(window).scrollTop();
  if( y > (h*.25) && y < (h*.75) ){
   // if we are show keyboardTips
   $("#tips").fadeIn("slow");
  } else {
   $('#tips').fadeOut('slow');
  }
 });
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can show an example of using `jQuery.noconflict` that didn't work?

Comment: Sure, here is the code: http://pastebin.com/34eW3Yjc

Comment: Did you try using `jQuery.` where `$.` was used? (Or `jQuery` in place of `$`?)

Comment: As well as calling `$.noConflict();` right after the jQuery include.

Answer (score 6):

You certainly can use `jQuery.` instead of `$.` but it's an awful lot of extra typing ( :) ).

In the rare situations where I have to mix Prototype and jQuery, I prefer to handle it like this.

Put jQuery in `noConflict` mode

```
<script>jQuery.noConflict()</script>
```

Then wrap your jQuery code in this:

```
(function($) {

    //Now I can do jQuery stuff and use the $
    $(document).ready( function() {

    });

})(jQuery)
```

What you're doing is creating an [anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140089/how-does-an-anonymous-function-in-javascript-work) that calls itself and you're passing the `jQuery` object to the function as an argument.

The beauty is that everything inside the function is local *only to that function* so you don't have to worry about the `$` inside the function stomping all over Prototype **and** you don't have to suffer the pain of converting jQuery code to Prototype.

Comment: I like the method you're describing... But *it's an awful lot of extra typing* is a matter of perspective, especially if it's easier to understand/get to work.

Comment: You'll save dozens of characters with my method!  DOZENS!  :)

Comment: Ok, that's pretty funny.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but i tried lmost everything jquery documentation gives on noConflict. My question was not on getting it working with jQuery, but on converting it to Prototype. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: @Mark Biek I tried your code, it still messes up my site.

Comment: @Mark Biek it messes the site when it comes to this part

    if( y > (h*.25) && y < (h*.75) )

Comment: Here is the error missing ) after condition
if ( y > (h*.25) && y

Comment: The problem was in less than char - <. I used the cdata trick and the page looks good, but the code still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `noConflict()` **right after** the jQuery include? **Before** any Prototype code is run?