# jQuery function declaration explanation

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, syntax, declaration

I've opened jQuery 1.7.1 library and wanted to study the code, but I've found a that functions are declared in strange way (for me). For example:

```
show: function() {
        //some code here
},
```

I learned to define function on this way:

```
function show() {
  //some code here
}
```

Can someone explain me why **show** function is not written on second way (like in most tutorials on internet)?

Comment: Are you leaving out some code in your first example? Seems like it is part of something bigger...

Comment: That function is a function expression which is assigned inside an object literal.

Comment: @AbeMiessler you are right, but code inside function is something that doesn't matter here, because I am asking just for function syntax explanation.

Comment: I'm talking about outside of function

Comment: @AbeMiessler The title is "jQuery function declaration explanation" as a logical step you think it may be part of, say, the jQuery object?

Comment: @AbeMiessler, you are right, that is a part of object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because it is within an object. [`Object Literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Object_Literals) have their properties defined in this way:

```
{
    name: value,
    //OR
    'name': value
}
```

Where value can be nearly anything such as a number, string, function, or even another object. In JavaScript you can also declare [`anonymous functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) and assign them to a variable. In fact, the following declarations have the same effect:

```
//declares the myFunc1 function
function myFunc1() {}
//declares an anonymous function and assigns it to myFunc2
var myFunc2 = function() {};

//you can now call either like so:
myFunc1();
myFunc2();
```

So, combining those two concepts if I have an object and I want one of its properties to be a function I would do it like so:

```
var myObj = {
    name: 'My Object',
    init: function() {
        return 'Initializing!';
    },
    version: 1.0
};

alert(myObj.init());
```

You would then get the output: `Initializing!`. Make sure to check out the great documentation and tutorials on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript), including their [JavaScript Tutorial Series](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Writing it the first way is in essence, setting a function as property of an object.

For example:

```
// I can create a new empty object
var myObject = {};

// or I can create a new object with a basic property
var myObject = { 
        color: "blue" 
    };

// I can also create an object with methods (like jQuery)
var myObject = { 
        color: "blue", 
        showColor: function(){ 
            alert(this.color); 
        } 
    };

// and you can use the object like this
myObject.showColor(); // calls the showColor method and will alert "blue"
```

This helps jQuery to encapsulate, namespace, and organize code.

Here are a couple of pretty good write-ups:

- [Why do you need to invoke an anonymous function on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140089/how-does-an-anonymous-function-in-javascript-work)
- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anonymous_Functions
- http://www.evotech.net/blog/2008/07/javascript-object-literals-a-definition/

Answer (score 2):

The first declaration, i.e., `show: function`, defines show to be a field in an object having type function. The second declares a function named show within the current scope (possibly global?)

Answer (score 1):

they're being described as a js object function. In this case:

```
var jQuery = {
    show: function(){
        //some code here
    }
}
```

so you access it like jQuery.show() for example.

I would say Chad's answer is most accurate for in depth research. You should look into them as they can revolutionize how you write js in a very clean way that is much less likely to conflict with other libraries.