# Insert object into empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have problem when running below code. `stock50` is quite normal array which contains 50 object with name and number (not empty).

`AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD` all look fine in console.log, but `EEE` only shows 9 elements and the last element is undefined. I've tried to change 9 to any number, but the last one always shows undefined. However, it's fine in JsFiddle.

stock50 array is just as below ....

```
runStockDraw : function(option){
  var pickingStock = stock50,
      tempArray = function(){
        var array =[],
            i = 0;

        while(i<10){
       // AAA  console.log(array[i-1]);
       // BBB  console.log(i);
          array[i] = {};
       // CCC  console.log(array[i]);
          array[i] = $.extend({},stock50[i]);
       // DDD  console.log(array[i]); 
          i++;
        }
       // EEE  console.log(array);
        return array; 
      }();


  var updateData = function(){
    var i = 0,j=0,
        temp = tempArray.shift(),
```

Comment: If it's fine in JsFiddle, what's your problem?

Comment: Self executing functions (which you are using) are usually required to have parens like this `(function() {})()`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492503/self-executing-function-syntax-and-callback-sytnax-explained) for more of an explanation.

Comment: @jfriend00 - That's true, but they are not required in this case, since it's a function expression. It does make it clearer what's going on though.

Comment: I found my problem is caused by 'temp = tempArray.shift()' ,  if I move it away, the code works fine ...