# Can anyone explain this line of javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using the DynaTree JavaScript tree and have been modifying it. Specifically I am trying to add multiple context menus dependent on the type of node.

Basically my idea was to have the context menu fire an ajax request to my MVC (2) controller, and it would pass this information as JSON, where it would be used to create a class that can be accessed in c#.

Ive got this working ok, after going through about 500 posts here! Now I need to modify the JS again in order to select an appropriate context menu dependant on type.

My list looks like

```
<div id="tree">
    <ul>

      <li id="'ID':1,'TYPE':1" title="Look: a tool tip!">item1 with key and tooltip</li>
      <li id="'ID':2,'TYPE':2" class="activate">item2: activated on init</li>
      <li id="'ID':3,'TYPE':3" class="folder">Folder with some children
        <ul>
          <li id="'ID':4,'TYPE':1">Sub-item 3.1</li>
          <li id="'ID':5,'TYPE':1">Sub-item 3.2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="'ID':6,'TYPE':1" class="expanded">Document with some children (expanded on init)
        <ul>
          <li id="'ID':7,'TYPE':1'">Sub-item 4.1</li>
          <li id="'ID':8,'TYPE':1'">Sub-item 4.2</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
      <li id="'ID':9,'TYPE':1" class="lazy folder">Lazy folder</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

And i return the ID and use jQuery.parseJSON to send to MVC.

The JS I dont understand is here:

```
function bindContextMenu(span) {
    // Add context menu to this node:
    debugger;

    $(span).contextMenu({ menu: "myMenu1" }, function (action, el, pos) {
      var node = $.ui.dynatree.getNode(el).toString();
      node = node.replace(/'/g, '\"');
      node = jQuery.parseJSON('{' + node + '}');

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/TreeView/Click/",
        data: { ID: node.ID, TYPE: node.TYPE },
        error: function (request) { $("#message").html("error"); },
        success: function (result) { $("#message").html("Success - " + result); }
      })
    });
  };
```

this line -  $(span).contextMenu({ menu: "myMenu1" }, function (action, el, pos) {

Seems to both set the contextmenu and also fires when a context menu is clicked. I'd be happy if someone could just provide some keywords for Google as i dont have a clue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: An aside: I'm not 100% clear on what you're intending to do here, but it seems like you're saying that every time the user clicks one of these tree items, you're going to do an AJAX call to get the context menu for the item? Unless you have a real need to have the context menu different for every single item, I'd embed the code for the context menu in the page and show it with some glue javascript; otherwise the user is going to be stuck waiting for your server every time they try to perform an ordinary UI action - opening a context menu; not to mention the load on your server.

Comment: Hi bloopletech, sorry I wasn't clear. The context menus are held in three lists hard coded in the html. The ajax part would do database type things behind the scenes associated with the context - IE a delete context click would go and delete something.

Comment: But basically my question is: $(span).contextMenu({ menu: "myMenu1" }, function (action, el, pos) { The keyword function appears without giving a function name. To my limited knowledge this isn't possible, what is this and what do i Google for?

Comment: Oh, that's an `anonymous function`; you're declaring the function and then passing the function as a parameter of the contextMenu function.

Comment: Thanks again, this will be a real help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.contextMenu` looks like a plugin, however without knowing exactly which plugin it is it is hard to give a definitive answer. However it looks like initialising that plugin takes 2 arguments:

1. The `object` containing any setup parameters - this is pretty standard for a plugin
2. The function which gets called when the menu is activated (possibly).

Comment: Thank you Jamie, I got so wrapped up in dyna tree I forgot it uses another plugin. Ill take a look at that now. Out of interest someone has said this may be a javascript closure, is this worth a google or is it the wrong direction.

Comment: @DavidBattersby This isnt a closure, but you might want to google that phase anyway as its a useful bit of knowledge ;)

Comment: What you're looking at (a function without a name) is an `anonymous function`. Here's a good detailed answer on javascript function s(and closures): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140089/how-does-an-anonymous-function-in-javascript-work

Comment: Thank you very much - I was actually just reading that link when i checked back here.