# How to create custom functions in Selenium IDE?

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

This should be possible according to  [JavaScript Functions in Selenium IDE HTML Tests](http://msquaredwebsvc.blogspot.ch/2007/10/javascript-functions-in-selenium-ide.html):

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>function(input) {return input.replace('foo', 'bar');}</td>
    <td>replaceText</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>replaceText('foo')</td>
    <td>var</td>
</tr>
```

Instead I get the following exception:

```
function statement requires a name
```

After giving it a name the statement runs:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>function replaceText(input) {return input.replace('foo', 'bar');}</td>
    <td>replaceText</td>
</tr>
```

But the next line fails to find the definition:

```
replaceText is not defined
```

I've also tried referencing the variable instead of the function:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>${replaceText}('foo')</td>
    <td>var</td>
</tr>
```

But apparently it's still undefined:

```
null is not a function
```

I also tried making an [anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140089/how-does-an-anonymous-function-in-javascript-work):

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>(function (input) {return input.replace('foo', 'bar')})</td>
    <td>replaceText</td>
</tr>
```

and running it with parentheses:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>(${replaceText})('foo')</td>
    <td>var</td>
</tr>
```

Error:

```
missing ) in parenthetical
```

and without:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>${replaceText}('foo')</td>
    <td>var</td>
</tr>
```

Error:

```
missing ; before statement
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a [self executing anonymous function](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=self-executing+anonymous+function):

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>(function(input) {return input.replace(input, 'bar');})('foo')</td>
    <td>replaceText</td>
</tr>
```

Note that you can also use your variables as parameters:

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>'foo'</td>
    <td>searchText</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>(function(input) {return input.replace(input, 'bar');})(${searchText})</td>
    <td>replaceText</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I test above,but I got a error "[error] Threw an exception: missing ) after argument list"
so,I change "${searchText}" to "storedVars['searchText']", it's ok :)

ps:JavaScript can be used with two types of Selenese parameters: script and non-script (usually expressions). In most cases, you’ll want to access and/or manipulate a test case variable inside the JavaScript snippet used as a Selenese parameter. All variables created in your test case are stored in a JavaScript associative array. An associative array has string indexes rather than sequential numeric indexes. The associative array containing your test case’s variables is named storedVars. Whenever you wish to access or manipulate a variable within a JavaScript snippet, you must refer to it as storedVars[‘yourVariableName’].

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#store-commands-and-selenium-variables

Answer (score 1):

Katranci's answer was really useful, but once I added in for loops the variables would lose scope.  I wound up using Katranci's solution inside window.eval().

```
window.eval('(function() { var trs = document.querySelectorAll(".my-list table tbody tr"); for (var x in trs) { var trc = trs[x].childNodes; for (var y in trc) { var html = trc[y].innerHTML; if (typeof html != "undefined" && html.match(/Selenium Testing/)) { return trs[x].className.replace(" lastrow", "");     }   } } } )();');
```

In this situation, I was creating test entries prefixed with 'Selenium Testing' and am using this code to identify those for subsequent test cases.  This happens to be a page without jquery.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to define a function and reuse it elsewhere:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>(function(){return function(min,max){return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min)) + min;} })()</td>
    <td>randomIntInRange</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>(function(){return storedVars['randomIntInRange'](10000,99999) +'-'+ storedVars['randomIntInRange'](1000,9999) })()</td>
    <td>randomZip</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${randomZip}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
...
[info] echo: 92105-3139
```

This works in Selenium IDE 2.9.0