# Date variable function to include in Selenium IDE future by x days in dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

I need to add a date in the future by x days in the format dd/mm/yyyy, the first step is to have a way to reliably get a date in the future.

eg. today is 18/3/2015 I'd like to have variable FollowUpDate be 4 days later on 22/3/2015

Consequently I am trying to add this function to Selenium IDE:

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days)
{
    var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
    dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
    return dat;
}

var dat = new Date();

alert(dat.addDays(5))
```

Reference: [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-datetime)

I have tried the following, with no luck, (using guidance from here: [How to create custom functions in Selenium IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377433/how-to-create-custom-functions-in-selenium-ide?rq=1) ) thanks for any suggestions out there...

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>new Date();</td>
    <td>today</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>(Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) { var dat = new Date(this.valueOf()); dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days); return dat; })var dat = storedVars['today'];dat.addDays(5)</td>
    <td>FollowUpDate</td>
</tr>
```

This results in an error: 
[error] Threw an exception: missing ; before statement

Other ideas:

- contemplating adding the function to the user-extension.js
- wondering if I should use another function? eg [Set date 10 days in the future and format to dd/mm/yyyy (e.g. 21/08/2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572561/javascript-set-date-10-days-in-the-future-in-this-format-dd-mm-yyyy-e-g-21-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a semi colon after the function:

```
dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days); return dat; });
```

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful. Your poke in the right direction was just the ticket ;-)