# javascript function, how to take the variable within document.write?

Tags: javascript, function, document.write

I need to call a variable inside a `document.write` but it doesnt work...
example

```
function(){
    var variable=document.getElementById("text");
    alert("your text "+ variable);
}
```

inside a table there is:

```
document.write('<td><input type="text" id="example"></td>');<br>
document.write('<td><input type="button" value="enter a text" onclick="function()">
```

Comment: The id seems to be incorrect... It should be : `document.getElementById("example")`.

Comment: It is never a good idea to use `document.write`. Have a look at innerHTML, insertBefore and appendChild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newFunction = function(){
    var variable=document.getElementById("text");
    alert("your text "+ variable);
}
document.write('<td><input type="button" value="enter a text" onclick="newFunction()">
```

Comment: Ty this is what i was searching :)
btw i forgot in function to write it correct but i know it was function NameFunction() sry

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous functions like below are allowed in javascript but we cannot call them by using `function(){}` from an element etc at a later time. They need to have a reference, in your case just a name after `function` will do

```
function(){        
  //Your code
}
```

Becomes

```
function myFunction(){ //myFunction can be changed to another more suitable name
  //Your code here;
}
```

Then from your `document.write` statement call your named function in the `onclick` event

```
document.write('<td><input type="text" id="example"></td>');<br>
document.write('<td><input type="button" value="enter a text" onclick="myFunction()">
```

now that you aren't using `function()` which is a reserved word in javascript but using `myFunction()` which javascript now thinks is your named function, it should work

Comment: Actually function(){} is perfectly valid. It creates an anonymous function. The problem is you can't call it with function(), because that is not the name of the function.

Answer (score 1):

`function` is a reserved keyword, you can't use it as a function name.

Comment: Well. There are anonymous javascript functions aren't there? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140089/how-does-an-anonymous-function-in-javascript-work But I'm guessing that's not the question at hand.

Comment: @Singular1ty — There are anonymous functions, but if you want to call them later then you have to store them somewhere, and then you can't use `onclick="function()"` because `function` isn't an acceptable name for a function!

Comment: Okay, interesting, didn't know that - but the OP didn't say whether or not he was calling the function via `onclick`. I think the issue is just element Id's being wrong.

Comment: @Singular1ty — Yes he did! That example is copy/pasted from the question!

Comment: yeah, missed that hiding down there. So anonymous functions are more like anonymous classes in Java - you can only call them for short things that you don't need to call again. Thanks for that. ;)

Comment: No, you can pass them around and store them in variables and have them live for as long as you like. You just have to make a point of storing them and you can't store them in a variable called function.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to reference which property of the Element you want to read. Simply using getElementById will return the object, not the value of the textfield. Use `getelementById('text').value`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much of your code there is real, and how much is just an example, but you need to double-check for your `getElementById()` and check that the ID you are providing is actually in the HTML.

In your example you show `getElementById("text")` but then don't have any HTML with an ID of `text`

Also, if you want to extract the content that is being stored inside that variable, you might want to get its value via `getElementById("text").value`

The main issue though, seems to be that you're using `function(){}` - you should name your function, for instance: `function foo(){}` and then use `onclick='foo()'` to call it.

Answer (score 0):

`function` is a reserved keyword.

You can use it like this

```
var func = function(){
    var variable=document.getElementById("text");
    alert("your text "+ variable);
}

onclick="func()"
```