# Difference between function with a name and function without name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

1.

```
function abc(){
    alert("named function");
}
```

v/s

2.

```
function(){
    alert("Un-Named function");
}
```

Kindly explain from beginners point.

Comment: The one with a name can be referenced by that name.  The one without a name can't, it's "anonymous."  Functionally they're identical.

Comment: Just try to call the function in your second example.

Comment: The second one is invalid syntax, and the code will throw a SyntaxError. To be used without a name, it will require evaluation within some expression.

Comment: Up-vote + Thank you for asking

Comment: what about this one: setTimeout (() => {}, time)    ????

Comment: The '()' there invokes the function immediately. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1140119/1526703) helped me.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

They work exactly the same. It's only in how you are able to run them that they are different.

So example #1 you could call again at any point with `abc();`. For example 2, you would either have to pass it as a parameter to another function, or set a variable to store it, like this:

```
var someFunction = function() {
    alert("Un-Named function");
}
```

Here's how to pass it into another function and run it.

```
// define it
function iRunOtherFunctions(otherFunction) {
    otherFunction.call(this);
}

// run it
iRunOtherFunctions(function() {
    alert("I'm inside another function");
});
```

As David mentions below, you can instantly call it too:

```
(function() {
    alert("Called immediately");
})(); // note the () after the function.
```

Comment: For completeness, another option for the anonymous function is to immediately call (or self-call) it: `(function() { alert('something'); })();`

Comment: Added more examples. Thanks David.

Comment: @Jordan, your last example needs to wrap the function like `(function(){})();` or `(function(){}());`.

Comment: @user2736012 not sure what you're talking about. The 2nd example works fine. I've already fixed the missing wrapped parens on the last example.

Comment: @Jordan: I was talking about the second example in the question. It's not valid syntax as shown. And then I was talking about your last example. You fixed it after my and cannon's comment.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misunderstood what you meant. Thanks for the clarification. My answer is fully correct now.

Comment: just wondering what is the point of such a function. it's not the same as just writing -  alert("called immediately"); as long as the function gets called immediately

Comment: Named functions and functions as variables are both used in procedural and object-oriented work. Anonymous functions like the final example are normally used in events, callbacks, and promises.

Comment: Would like to know about this kind of anonymous function (() =>{});, lets see if I fill this function ((response)=>{alert(response.data);});

Answer (score 2):

Both can be used to achieve the same but the main difference is the anonymous functions don't need a name. Anonymous functions are functions that are dynamically declared at runtime. They’re called anonymous functions because they aren’t given a name in the same way as normal functions.

Please refer this [link](http://helephant.com/2008/08/23/javascript-anonymous-functions/)