# simple javascript: "Reference Error: 'click' is undefined"

Tags: javascript, function

So I'm making a satirical cookie-clicker based game as my first ever JS game.

I made a JSFiddle. (The image won't show, but the image is supposed to be a swag hat, which you click to get swag points.) My code is simple so far, but I was wondering why it told me my click() function was undefined. It's mentioned in the head and I don't know what's wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/69mJq/

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Swag Dealr</title>
    <script src="swagdealr.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>

    <h3>SWAG DEALR</h3>
    <a href="JavaScript:click()"><img src="img/swaghat.png"></a>
    <p>grams of swag</p>
    <p id="swagnumber"></p>
    <p id=></p>

</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
Game={};

Game.Launch = function() {
}




window.onload = function() {
    Game.Load();
};        

Game.Load = function() {
    var swagAmount = 0;
    function click() {
        swagAmount + (1 * swagMultiplier) = swagAmount;
        document.getElementById("swagnumber").innerHTML = swagAmount;
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you doing ?. what is this code for?

Comment: I'm creating an image in my HTML file; clicking on the image will execute click(); and the function is defined in the JS file but the command line in Chrome tells me that click() is undefined every time I click the image.

Comment: I'm a newb so I decided to start off with something easy that could grow bigger; so I started off with a cookie-clicker type game where clicking the hat image (broken in JSFiddle) would give you points.

Comment: Are you using any Javascript framework? like JQuery?

Comment: None, just plain JS and HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your JS as mentioned below :

```
Game={};

Game.Launch = function() {
}

window.onload = function() {
    Game.Load();
};     

Game.Load = function() {
}   

var swagAmount = 0;
function click() {
        swagAmount = swagAmount + (1 * swagMultiplier);
        document.getElementById("swagnumber").innerHTML = swagAmount;
    }
```

**Note:** One thing I have noticed that **swagMultiplier** is not defined anywhere.

Comment: It sent me to a nonexistent subdirectory in my files called /documents/swagdealr/click() and didn't work.

Comment: Updated my answer. keep click event out of the **Game.Load** and define **swagMultiplier** as I mentioned in my note

Comment: Thanks, got it. I got rid of swagMultiplier and pulled swagAmount out and made it a global var.

Comment: will define swagMultiplier

Answer (score 2):

```
Game={};
Game.Load = function() {
    var swagAmount = 0;
    Game.click(swagAmount);

}  
Game.click = function(swagAmount) {
    var swagMultiplier= 5
    swagAmount = swagAmount + (1 * swagMultiplier) ;
    document.getElementById("swagnumber").innerHTML = swagAmount;
}
Game.Load();
```

I have defined `swagMultiplier` and its working fine. Change the href as

```
<a href="Game.click()"><img src="img/swaghat.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because your click() method is wrapped in an anonymous function. Drag it outside and it will work:

```
Game.Load = function() {
    var swagAmount = 0;
}
function click() {...}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyWorker/69mJq/6/

Comment: It got rid of the 'click is undefined' error but now it's giving me the error "Invalid left-hand side in assignment".

Comment: Yes, I noticed it, too. You have to check your code where I commented out. Don't you feel "swagAmount + (1 * swagMultiplier) = swagAmount;" might not be a valid statement?

Comment: Haha, funny comment, though it was not an "anonymous function". ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140089/how-does-an-anonymous-function-in-javascript-work

Comment: Interesting. If it's not an anonymous function, what's the name? Search this article (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) with "anonymous function" and check the first result.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You had it out of [Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope).

Long answer:

```
Game.Load = function() {
  var swagAmount = 0;
  function click() {
    swagAmount = swagAmount + (1 * + "swagMultiplier?");
    document.getElementById("swagnumber").innerHTML = swagAmount;
    console.log('clicked')
  }
  window.click = click;
}
```

You had the `swagAmount =` reversed, thus giving a `left hand assignment error`.
And what is `swagMultiplier`, you never had it assigned, so I put it in `""` to acknowledge that.

## JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/69mJq/7/

Answer (score 0):

We have two problems in your code

1. You are assigning it wrongly

> ```
> swagAmount + (1 * swagMultiplier) = swagAmount;
> ```

It should be

> swagAmount = swagAmount + (1 * swagMultiplier);

1. You are adding the click event to a Game.Load ( even though its possible), for the sake of simplicity we can add the click method to the Game object.

Sample code

```
 Game.click = function () {
    swagAmount = swagAmount + (1 * swagMultiplier);
        document.getElementById("swagnumber").innerHTML = swagAmount;
 }
```

JS Fiddle Demo At [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gw47A/1/)

**NOTE**:

We need to stop the default behaviour of the link using event.preventDefault()