# Javascript callback functions differences

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know the difference between 2 implementations of callback functions.

This:

```
$("#button").on('click', function () {
            //do something
});
```

Versus having the function already defined.

```
$("#button").on('click', btnFunction);
function btnFunction() {
    //do something
}
```

Are there any implications with one compared to another? Performance-wise is one faster?

Comment: There's no functional difference, and no noticeable performance difference either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first uses an anonymous function and the second does not. There's no difference in both.

See: 
[Why do you need to invoke an anonymous function on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140089/how-does-an-anonymous-function-in-javascript-work)

Answer (score 2):

Some folks prefer the second form because it gives a function name when using the debugger and tracing, but there are ways to get the same functionality in the first form.

If you are attaching and removing the event handler based on changing conditions, the second form is *much* easier to maintain, however.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference at all, and there's no performance issue with neither one of them. The only difference is that in one of them you're defining the callback function as an anonymous function, this way you cannot reuse it.

The other way, where you define it else where and named it and then pass it as a callback, you're defining a function that you can later reuse in another part of your code.

For example: if you want to do something when the document is ready, and then do se exact same thing when some one press a button you can use something like this:

```
function getData() {
    //do something
}

$(function() {
    // Call the function once the DOM is ready
    getData();
});

// Call the same function when the button is clicked
$("#refresh_button").on('click', getData);
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the first one will be used, called [Anonymous Functions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anonymous_Functions)

The second one will be used when the function is not only used inlined here, but also needs to be reused somewhere else.

But anyway it could be a personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

The only real difference you could see is that stack trace (if an exception is thrown for example) will be better, i.e. easier to debug, when using the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Just reuse-ability.

In the second case, you could call `btnFunction()` somewhere else if need be.