# Where does the event-variable come from?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand this javascript-code:

```
  onMouseMoved = (function(_this) {
    return function(event) {
      dx = (event.pageX/3) / window.innerWidth;
      dy = (event.pageY/3) / window.innerHeight;
      return tr = Math.atan2(hy, hx);
    };
  })(this);
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMoved, false);
```

Why does the outer function return a function and where does the event-variable come from?

Comment: The variable is your parameter. Or do you ask where the value comes from?

Comment: That's coffee-script generated code, isn't it? The reason for the IEFE is that the compiler isn't very clever.

Comment: You should use `->` instead of `=>` if you don't use `this` inside the function. Makes the generated code much clearer.

Comment: I don't write coffee-script, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the outer function return a function

Because:

(a) It has a return statement in front of a function expression

and

(b) The returned function is used as an argument to a function that expects that argument be a function

> where does the event-variable come from

From the native browser code that implements the event listener routines (according to [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventListener) for `addEventListener`)

Answer (score 1):

The first function is an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) it executes right away and returns another function that is set as the callback for the event handler.

It could also be written like this

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMoved, false);

function onMouseMoved(event) {
    dx = (event.pageX/3) / window.innerWidth;
    dy = (event.pageY/3) / window.innerHeight;
    return tr = Math.atan2(hy, hx);
};
```

or this

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    dx = (event.pageX/3) / window.innerWidth;
    dy = (event.pageY/3) / window.innerHeight;
    return tr = Math.atan2(hy, hx);
}, false);
```

This would be exactly the same, but we wouldn't have the value of `_this`, which seems like the reason for the IIFE, locking in the outer value of `this`, but that function argument is never used, so it doesn't seem like it's neccessary here.

So the event argument is coming from the native [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

For a thorough explanation as to how the IIFE works, see this
[Why do you need to invoke an anonymous function on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140089/how-does-an-anonymous-function-in-javascript-work?rq=1)