# Firefox extension warning: JavaScript namespace pollution

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Firefox addon example:

```
    var MyAddonNamespace = {
        local_variable: null,
        local_method: function() {
            return 'string';
        }
    };

window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
    MyAddonNamespace.local_method();
}, false);
```

> Warning: Your add-on contains a large number of global variables, which can conflict with other add-ons. For more information, see http://blog.mozilla.com/addons/2009/01/16/firefox-extensions-global-namespace-pollution/, or use JavaScript modules.

How I can fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be a false-positive, or might be some other script you include... Cannot say given the limited information

Answer (score 0):

You can hide variables from the global scope by putting them into an anonymous function ([explanation of anymous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140089/how-does-an-anonymous-function-in-javascript-work)).

In your case that would look as follows:

```
(function(){
    var MyAddonNamespace = {
       local_variable: null,
       local_method: function() {
          return 'string';
       }
   };
   window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
      MyAddonNamespace.local_method();
   }, false);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks. But I tried it and have a error: MyAddonNamespace is not defined. How I can use MyAddonNamespace methods in xul?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have never worked with XUL. Is there any other place outside the anonymous function where you try to access MyAddonNamespace?