# JS - (function(){} ()) What does it do?

Tags: javascript

I am trying something and I saw Facebook SDK's code:

```
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Can someone explain to me what does `(function(){}())` do? I can't Google it since brackets are consider a syntax on Google.

Comment: It's an IIFE, it will be called just after creation.

Comment: also [Why do you need to invoke an anonymous function on the same line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140089/why-do-you-need-to-invoke-an-anonymous-function-on-the-same-line)

Comment: "I can't Google it" - [try SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%28function%28%29{}%29%28%29)!

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester Wow! Never heard of that! Thank you, I learnt a new thing.

Comment: @YuliamChandra, but the last bracket is inside, does that matter?

Comment: @DanielCheung, same thing different combination