# Timing of button.onclick execution

Tags: javascript

I'm just learning JS and I'm using the Head First books. In one of the lessons, the following code is given to set up an event handler for a button:

```
window.onload = init

function init() {
    var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
    button.onclick = handleButtonClick;
}
function handleButtonClick() {
    alert("Button has been pressed");   
}
```

When I test the code in the browser, the alert pops up when I click the button, as expected. So I rearranged some things and tried this, just to see what would happen:

```
window.onload = init

function init() {
    var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
    button.onclick = alert("Button has been pressed");
}
```

Now the alert shows up as soon as the page loads, but I can't figure out why. Why doesn't the alert wait until the button is clicked? I'm a complete newb at JS and programming in general. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose it in a function, or it will execute immediately:

```js
window.onload = init

function init() {
    var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
    button.onclick = function(){ alert("Button has been pressed") };
}
```

```html
<button id="addButton">Alert</button>
```

This occurs because you're trying to assign `alert()` to the `onclick` property of a button, which is not possible. JavaScript often fails "nicely," acting oddly rather than throwing errors in an attempt to prevent webpages from breaking entirely. When it sees the `alert()`, it executes immediately.

If you wrap it in a function, you can assign the function to the `onclick` property and it will work as expected.

Comment: Will properties only accept functions as assignments in general? Is this just an arbitrary rule of JS?

Comment: @Brett It depends on the property, but not always. `onclick` assigns an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) to the given element, so you need to pass a function for the value.

Answer (score 1):

It is expected. Javascript would run `alert("Button has been pressed");` you might want to change it to  `button.onclick = function() {alert("Button has been pressed"); };`

Useful reading about this:

> [Why do you need to invoke an anonymous function on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140089/why-do-you-need-to-invoke-an-anonymous-function-on-the-same-line)
>
> http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Answer (score 0):

Yep, `onclick` takes a function - simply passing `alert()` will execute immediately. You need to do:

```
button.onclick = function() {
    alert("Button has been pressed");
}
```