# Getting data from the HTML form into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the values from the form inputs once you click submit into variables in JavaScript.

However I don't seem to be having much luck as the console log just shows the variables as empty.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset><legend>Registration</legend>
<form action="#" method="post" id="theForm">
    <label for="username">Username<input type="text" name="username" id="username"></label>
    <label for="name">Name<input type="text" name="name" id="name"></label>
    <label for="email">Email<input type="email" name="email" id="email"></label>
    <label for="password">Password<input type="password" name="password" id="password"></label>
    <label for="age">Age<input type="number" name="age" id="age"></label>
    <input type="hidden" name="unique" id="unique">
    <input type="submit" value="Register!" id="submit">
</form>
</fieldset>

<div id="output"></div>

<script src="js/process.js"></script>    

</body>

</html>
```

JS

```
var output = document.getElementById('output');

function addUser() {
    'use strict';
    var username = document.getElementById('username');
    var name = document.getElementById('name');
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var password = document.getElementById('password');
    var age = document.getElementById('age');
    console.log(username.value);
    console.log(name.value);
    console.log(password.value);
}

// Initial setup:
function init() {
    'use strict';
    document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = addUser();
} // End of init() function.
//On window load call init function
window.onload = init;
```

**EDIT** It was because I needed to remove () on addUser and also add return false to the addUser function at the bottom.

Comment: why is your script outside the head and body tags? move it just before the end `body` tag.

Comment: @karthikr mistake on my part, its updated now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
function init() {
    'use strict';
    document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = addUser();
}
```

This will set the `onsubmit` equal to undefined because addUser returns nothing.
To get the function addUser as the onsubmit function use this instead.

```
function init() {
    'use strict';
    document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = addUser;
}
```

You are trying to pass the function itself not the return of it.

Also, when I'm making functions that will be passed or set, I find it more reasonable to write them like this:

```
var addUser = function(){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) That was one of the problems! It seems I also had to have 'returns false' at the end of the function too any idea why that is?

EDIT: Often, in event handlers, such as onsubmit, returning false is a way to tell the event to not actually fire. So, say, in the onsubmit case, this would mean that the form is not submitted.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your function working, you might want to do this:

```
   function init() {
        'use strict';
        document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = function () { addUser(); }
    }
```

You can refer to the post below for further explanation:

> [Timing of button.onclick execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290660/timing-of-button-onclick-execution/26290699#26290699)

Hope it helps!