# Difference between declared function with name and without name

Tags: javascript

can anybody tell me whats the difference between this two examples:

```
//difference with this:
var x = function withName(a,b,c) {} //why i should declare a name here?

//and this
var y = function (a,b,c) {}
```

Comment: From my personal experience: Function names help debugging when you read a call stack, but I found this huge explanation, with lots of background, that can explain that better: https://kangax.github.io/nfe/

Comment: @ClementAmarnath It's not a duplicate of that. This question is about "named function expressions", not function declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this particular case, there is no difference. But in general, the fact that the function assigned to a variable has a name, makes it possible to invoke the function from inside the same function ([recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)).

Answer (score 1):

According to the ECMA specification, a function can be written either through declaration or through expression,

Declaration is writing function as below,

```
function withName(a,b,c) {

}
```

With declaration, it is required to write an identifier which in this case is `withName`

Both the example that you have given are of function expression where it is not required to write the identifier i.e. `withName` as you can still call this function with the variable `x` or `y`

```
var x = function withName(a,b,c) {} 

var y = function (a,b,c) {}
```

However, the only difference here is that if you don't specify the identifier you are creating a anonymous funtion.

You can see [**this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140089/why-do-you-need-to-invoke-an-anonymous-function-on-the-same-line) for detailed explanation.