# why add this $(function () { at the first line of the javascript file?

Tags: javascript, closures

```
$(function () {
 console.log('hello');
 //...
})
```

I saw the code like this. Don't know the purpose of adding the first line (function)? Could Someone explain this?

Comment: Have you tried to do any research on this elsewhere?

Comment: Please search before you ask. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140089/why-do-you-need-to-invoke-an-anonymous-function-on-the-same-line

Comment: Official docs : https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping you Javascript code with `$(function () {`:

```
$(function () {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

is the same (a **Shorthand** version) as writing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Which ensures the script will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for Javascript code to execute ([Jquery docs](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)).

Answer (score 1):

That is just jQuery short-hand for

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... });
```

Comment: It's *probably* jQuery, but it could be some other library too.