# What does the "$" sign mean in jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What is the meaning of “$” sign in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150381/what-is-the-meaning-of-sign-in-javascript)

Why do we use the dollar (`$`) symbol in jQuery and JavaScript?
I always put a dollar in my scripts but I actuary don't know why.

For an example:

```
$('#Text').click(function () {
  $('#Text').css('color', 'red')
});
```

This just changes the text colour when you click it, but it demonstrates my point.

Comment: Thanks all, I know it was a stupid question!

Comment: Not necessarily a stupid question.  Just do some research ahead of time.  You'd be surprised, a google search will more often than not result in links to questions/answers on stackoverflow

Comment: Guys you are sometimes to hard on posters. I'm always happy when I google something and I have a well documented SO Q&A page with all of my stupid questions answered as a first result.

Comment: There are no stupid questions period.

Comment: @GeekMasher there's no stupid questions, only unprepared ones.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In JavaScript it has no special significance (no more than `a` or `Q` anyway). It is just an [uninformative variable name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting).

In jQuery the variable is assigned a copy of the `jQuery` function. This function is heavily overloaded and means half a dozen different things depending on what arguments it is passed. In this particular example you are passing it a string that contains a selector, so the function means "Create a jQuery object containing the element with the id *Text*".

Answer (score 50):

The `$` is just a function. It is actually an alias for the function called `jQuery`, so your code can be written like this with the exact same results:

```
jQuery('#Text').click(function () {
  jQuery('#Text').css('color', 'red');
});
```

Answer (score 17):

In jQuery, the $ sign is just an alias to `jQuery()`, then an alias for a function.

[This](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp) page reports:

> Basic syntax is: $(selector).action()
>
> - A dollar sign to define jQuery
> - A (selector) to "query (or find)" HTML elements
> - A jQuery action() to be performed on the element(s)

Answer (score 8):

The jQuery syntax is tailor made for selecting HTML elements and perform some action on the element(s).

Basic syntax is: $(selector).action()

A dollar sign to define jQuery
A (selector) to "query (or find)" HTML elements
A jQuery action() to be performed on the element(s)

[More on this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp)

Comment: That's only partially true. The meaning changes depending on the arguments given. Don't reference W3Schools please, they are dreadful.

Comment: WRT W3Schools, see [w3fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Answer (score 2):

The `$` symbol simply invokes the jQuery library's selector functionality. So `$("#Text")` returns the jQuery object for the `Text` `div` which can then be modified.

Comment: Not entirely true. It *might* invoke the selector functionality, it depends what arguments you pass it.

Answer (score 1):

Additional to the jQuery thing treated in the other answers there is another meaning in JavaScript - as prefix for the RegExp properties representing matches, for example:

```js
"test".match( /t(e)st/ );
alert( RegExp.$1 );
```

will alert "e"

But also here it's not "magic" but simply part of the properties name

Comment: From the context, that clearly isn't the case here. (And that code throws an exception for me)

Comment: @Quentin It's sort of the case since the question just was what the `$` sign means. This is a part of the complete answer. And sorry, you were right, it did throw an exception since I had a Typo in spelling `RegExp` but now it's correct.