# difference between $ and $$

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used `$` instead of `document.getElementById()` in javascript and i don't know what is the use of `$$`. Can any one please tell me what is the use of `$$`?

Here is the code:

```
var link_object = $$('a[class="menu_item"]');
if (window.location.href.search('inident.do') >= 0) {
    link_object.each(function (elem) {
        if (elem.innerHTML == 'Create an Incident') {
            elem.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
            elem.style.color = 'black';
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How did you find out about `$$` to begin with?

Comment: From where did you find $$?

Comment: $ is the global jQuery object. Maybe someone assigned other value to $$?

Comment: Your basic understanding of `$` itself is wrong (check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8667736/1671639)).

Comment: I assume you are playing in developer console? If so `$$` is a shortcut for `document.querySelectorAll`. It's not jQuery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Double Dollar Sign](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463867/javascript-double-dollar-sign)

Comment: see this var object = $$('a[class="menu_item"]');

Comment: Can you post a code sample containing `$$`? There is nothing like $$ in jQuery, but it can be another function.

Comment: @Praveen why it is wrong? Functions are also objects in javascript :)

Comment: Maybe juste a typo ? What's the output of console.log($$); ?

Comment: @DawidC Yeah. But OP mentioned it `$` instead of `document.getElementById()`.   whereas in jQuery its `$('#..')` (we still use different selectors).   if it is custom method method written by OP then I take my word back :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single $ is usually a short name for jQuery object.
The double $$ could be anything.

In Angular, seems to designate a private identifier.

You can do something like this when you hate your colleagues :

```
$$$$($$$[$]);
```

Comment: and this could be a comment

Comment: This is my answer, so no.

Comment: @AmitJoki: It's also a perfectly valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

$ is the selector in jquery. $$ doesn't have any specific meaning in jquery
 so you can use it in your own way.
 like this

```
     function $$(){
        alert('hello');
      }

    $$();
```

There may be other libraries like jquery which use $ or may be use $$.
since $ is valid symbol in javascript for variable and function names
it is the best way to simplify the dom selection instead of using long
document.getElementById() like functions.

contribution of Mr. Robg

In jQuery, $ is a function that takes different types arguments. It will accept functions, arrays, objects (native and host), strings or nothing at all. If it gets a string, it will work with a selector or HTML

Comment: In jQuery, [*$*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) is a function that takes different types of arguments. It will accept functions, arrays, objects (native and host), strings or nothing at all. If it gets a string, it will work with a selector or HTML.

Comment: @RobG Thank you i've include this :-)

Answer (score 0):

$$ doesn't have any particular meaning for jQuery. But if you are using some library who can conflict with jQuery, you can change the name of $ function to anything you want by using [jQuery noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) function;

You should look for something like this early in your code

```
var $$ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is jQuery ? It looks like [mootools](http://mootools.net/).

In mootools, [$$()](http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.5.1/Element/Element#Window:dollars) is the element selector function. It works similar to $() in jQuery.

```
$('id')
```

returns the element with id 'id'.

```
$$('selector')
```

returns a collection of the elements corresponding to the selector passed.