# Variable declaration using $

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below declaration of $. is meant to be a javascript variable ?

I understand how to use $ for selectors

```
$('#Text').click(function () {
  $('#Text').css('color', 'red')
});
```

But when I declare variable I was used to declare that as `var x = function(){}...`

What this notation means "$." is a jquery way of declaring variables ?

```
$.searchTwitter= function(){


                    $.ajax({
                        url:"http://search.twitter.com/search.json",
                        data:{
                                q:'dogs'
                        },
                        dataType:'jsonp',
                        success:function(results){
                            console.log(results);
                        }
                    });
               };

 $.searchTwitter();
```

Comment: It just creates scope;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the $ sign mean in Jquery or JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667736/what-does-the-sign-mean-in-jquery-or-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dollar sign is one of the chars allowed in variable names in Javascript, along with numbers, underscores and English letters.

Examples for 'special' variable names are:

`$$ 
$_ 
$ 
_`

Dot notation is a way to assign a property to an object.

Example:

```
var x = { myName: 'Roman' };
x.searchTwitter = function() {}; 
x.searchTwitter();
console.log(x.myName);
```

When a browser loads the Jquery library, Jquery declares a global variable named Jquery and also declares an alias for it - the $.

Answer your question is no, it's not a special way of Jquery declaring variables. It's standard Javascript way of adding properties to an object.

Answer (score 3):

In **jQuery**, `$` is an alias for `jQuery`.

**i.e.** 
`$.ajax();` works same as `jQuery.ajax();`

In **Javascript**, `$` is nothing special; just simply a valid JavaScript identifier.

Ref: https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

> **Note**: The jQuery library exposes its methods and properties via two properties of the window object called jQuery and $. $ is simply
>   an alias for jQuery and it's often employed because it's shorter and
>   faster to write.

Comment: $, Jquery is an object or a function ?

Comment: @Cris: In JavaScript, every function is an object and, thus, may have properties.

Answer (score 2):

`$` is jQuery itself. It's declared in the jQuery library. When you use `$.searchTwitter = function(){}` what you're really saying is `JQuery.searchTwitter = function(){}`.

Answer (score 1):

`$` is known as [Syntactic Sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)

In case of jQuery it is jQuery Object. What that means is that, using `$("#mydiv")` or `jQuery("#mydiv")` is the same. `$` only eases the pain of writing the full object name `jQuery`.

If you want to [know more](http://www.authenticsociety.com/blog/JavaScript_DollarSign)

Answer (score 1):

`$` is a global variable defined by jQuery and an alias for the variable `jQuery`. By assigning `$.searchTwitter = function() { ... }` one adds a new method to the global `jQuery` object.

Practically, there is no advantage or disadvantage of such a declaration in contrast with the usual `function searchTwitter() { ... }` syntax. It is sometimes used to declare functions which are related to `jQuery` or are a plug-in for `jQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

For safety reasons I like to wrap my code with closure function with **$** as argument. See code below:

```js
(function($){
  
 $.searchTwitter = function(){

    $.ajax({
      url:"http://search.twitter.com/search.json",
      data:{
        q:'dogs'
      },
      dataType:'jsonp',
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        $('#errors').html(JSON.stringify(xhr));
      },
      success:function(results){
        console.log(results);
        $('#results').html(JSON.stringify(results));
      }
    });
 };
 $.searchTwitter();

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div><div id="errors"></div>
```

but Cris this Twitter API is deprecated. It should not work.

[image]