# General Javascript Syntax Query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to Javascript and its syntaxes. Hope you all can help clear my doubts.

Q1)

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {...}
</script>
```

What does the "$(document...." part mean? I thought a function is started with

```
function(var){...}
```

? What the Difference? and when do i use "$" symbol?

Q2)

Js code

```
$('#dropzone').on('dragover', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
            });
```

Html code

```
  <div id="dropzone">
        <span>Drop an image file here</span>
        <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
```

Based on the above, I see that "#dropzone" is linked to the "div id='dropzone'", correct? and i dont get the part of " function(e)"? what role does puting a function at that spot denotes?

Thank For your replies :)

Comment: `$` is a shortcut reference to `jQuery` as long as it's loaded on the page. `.ready` is a special `jQuery` function that can only be called on the `document` which calls whatever function (`function() {...}`) it wraps when the page is done loading. You're very new, so learn JavaScript syntax first and when this all makes sense, you can move onto `jQuery` and the `$` syntax. The `.on` is similar to JavaScript's `.addEventListener`. Again, learn the basics first. Make some playful apps and read a **lot** of tutorials. JavaScript is fun once you understand it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the links for more thorough explanations

Q1: `$(document).ready` essentially detects that the given page state is ready for manipulation.

Q1 part 2: `$` is a copy of the `jQuery` function and can be used for many varying desired results by creating a `jQuery` object of a given element.

Q2:  Essentially shorthand for `"events"` that is often passed to event handlers.  In your example, The `.on()` method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the `jQuery` object. I've provided a link to that as well at the bottom.

[Explanation for Q1: $(document).ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

[Explanation for Q1 part 2: $](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667736/what-does-the-sign-mean-in-jquery-or-javascript)

[Explanation for Q2: function(e) in the given context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323392/in-javascript-jquery-what-does-e-mean)

[Additional reading: .on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Thank You for your help. :)