# Use both $ and jquery as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my project every page loads a cdn jquery script. some use $ and some use jquery. and now I have to use my new script file 'myNewScript.js' in every page.

If I write my function like `$(function (){})` it gives error on some pages like

> *$ is not function*

and if I write function like this `jquery(function (){})` then it also give error on other page like

> *jquery is not a function*.

I want to know can we use both `$` and `jquery` as variable . like in same script file say ***'myNewScript.js'*** I want to write `$(function (){})` and `jquery(function (){})`.

Every thing is dependent on each other so I can't reverse the loading of the script. I can't think of any solution...

Comment: Load the jQueries with [noconflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) - to be safe use jQuery instead of $ if you have scripts that rename $

Comment: They are the same. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667736/what-does-the-sign-mean-in-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: you could check if $ is defined and if not then assign jquery to $

Comment: @AHBagheri they are not the same if a script renames $

Comment: @pawanKumar `jquery` check the `Q` case in upper `jQuery`.

Comment: Not clear to me. Are you loading `myNewScript.js` before or after jQuery library?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery should always be available using the name `jQuery` (note the uppercase Q). So use that:

```
jQuery(function (){})
```

You can also wrap your code in an IIFE if you would like to refer to jQuery as `$` while dealing with the uncertainty whether the global `$` actually refers to it:

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        // on ready stuff
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define jQuery locally for yourself by looking for both variables.

```
var myJquery = jquery || $;
```

Comment: That will break all scripts that use $ on that page if $ is not jQuery on that page

Comment: _If I write my function like $(function (){}) it gives error on some pages like $ is not function and if I write function like this jquery(function (){}) then it also give error on other page like jquery is not a function._......read the question.

Comment: The do `var myJquery = jquery || $;

Comment: if I do like @rya