# What is $$$ in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667736/what-does-the-sign-mean-in-jquery-or-javascript) $ in as alias for [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150381/what-is-the-meaning-of-sign-in-javascript).

Can someone please enlighten me what three dollars mean in java script? I am seeing both of the following are working.

```
var stxx = new CIQ.ChartEngine({ container: $$$("#idOfDev") });
var stxx = new CIQ.ChartEngine({ container: $$$(".classAppliedToDev") });
```

Both of them are selecting the dev to which id or class is applied.

But strangely when I make it single $ instead of three $$$, it would not work.

Comment: It's just a variable name, just like `$`. To figure out what exactly it is there, you'll have to look at the context of that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are referencing ChartIQ SDK. Looking at their documentation they provide the explanation behind these variables

http://documentation.chartiq.com/global.html#__$__anchor

> **$$(id [, source])**
>
> Shorthand for getElementById(). Equivalent to prototype style $() which is faster but less powerful than jquery style $()

and then

> **$$$(selector [, source])**
>
> Functional equivalent of querySelector(). Functionally equivalent to jquery $(). This uses querySelectorAll in order to maintain compatibility with IE 9. Note that if multiple objects match the selector then only the first will be returned.