# Javascript function declarations with a dollar sign

Tags: javascript

This function declaration doesn't make sense to me. What does the $ sign do?

```
function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
```

Also, this code is interfering with other Javascript code. If I comment it out, then the other Javascript code I'm trying to use works, but then I lose some other functionality.

Why might it be interfering with my other code.

Comment: Some JavaScript ninja you are :/

Comment: [What is the meaning of “$” sign in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150381/what-is-the-meaning-of-sign-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You are declaring a function called `$` that wraps `document.getElementById`, apparently for convenience.** Nothing special.

Reference [What characters are valid for JavaScript variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names)

---

As for the interference, there is likely another global variable called `$`, which is being clobbered. See [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: Yes, jQuery is being used. So how can I change this variable so that the conflict goes away?

Comment: @javascriptninja rename the function to something unique. It will be difficult to determine where _that_ function is being called tho, so you can update..

Answer (score 4):

> What does the $ sign do?

Nothing special. It is just a character that can be used in variable/function names.

There has been a trend to use `$` as the name to the gateway function for a number of libraries (including Mootools, Prototype and jQuery). This has two major problems:

- It makes them conflict with each other
- It violates the principles of [self-documenting code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting)

> Also, this code is interfering with other Javascript code.

Presumably something else is using a variable called `$` then.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript variables can start (and only consist of) a `$` (amongst others).

Previously, the `$` was added solely for machine generated variables.

This was in the spec I believe, but has since been removed (don't quote me).

> Dollar sign was added to the language specifically for use by code
>   generators and macro processes, so if you have machines writing code
>   then the machines need to be confident that the variables that they
>   create will not conflict with variables that the humans are going to
>   create. To distinguish them, we’ll allow the machines to use dollar
>   sign. Some of the ninjas found out about that and thought oh, dollar
>   sign, I can use dollar sign as a function name, so they’re out there
>   doing that. And it looks stupid. I mean, look at a program with dollar
>   sign.

[Source: Douglas Crockford](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui//theater/video.php?v=crockonjs-2).

If it is interfering with other code, you may be using a library which uses this identifier. If that's the case, look at the *no conflict* mode for that library (if it has one).

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess: are you  using jQuery or prototype?

`$` and `_` are valid characters in variable/function names. The code is the same as declaring `function a(id) {return document.getElementById(id);}`.

It's typically used as a shortcut for selecting an element because typing `document.getElementById` is much too long for how often it's used.