# $('#background .image img') - What does .image mean?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to teach myself jquery while reading someone else's code, and I found this line of code:

```
var b = $('#background .image img');
```

I don't see any documentation for it - any idea what it could mean?

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of "$" sign in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150381/what-is-the-meaning-of-sign-in-javascript)

Comment: Er, I don't want to know what $ means, I want to know what .image means.

Comment: Realized that it was just a CSS selector for the class image, as per TimWolla.

Comment: Well, "it" wasn't really enough to tell which part you were asking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will select elements based on that CSS-Selector: Any `<img>` in an element with the class `image`, that is in an element with the ID `background`

Comment: No. That is wrong. This would be `$("#background img.image")`.

Comment: @iblue "in an element with the class" ;)

Answer (score 2):

It selects all `<img>` tags inside elements with class `image` inside the element with id `background`.