# What does $ do when using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reading JavaScript and JQuery, The Missing Manual

and they start of with this Snippet :

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

I know that `function(){}` is an anonymous function, and that document is an object with properties I can set / read, and that ready() is a JQuery function defined in the library, but I don't know what the rest of the syntax is for and it is not explained in the book.

Particularly,

```
$(document)
```

Can someone explain what this does or point me to a link?  Also, someone said that you can identify JQuery by this alone, is this true?

Comment: You should try google, it will point you to http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: `$` is a reference to `window.jQuery`, which is a function that is overloaded with various types of behavior depending on what it is passed.

Comment: i do not think someone who wants to break down the guts of statement that most people overlook deserves downvotes...

Comment: I agree. I upvoted his question. It's a logical question that deserves to be answered with _tact & fact_

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of "$" sign in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150381/what-is-the-meaning-of-sign-in-javascript)

Comment: It seems from the documentation that jQuery is a function..so that $(document) is a function as well...can someone verify?

Comment: Regarding your update... *"Is jQuery() a function or an object?"*, it's both. Functions in JavaScript are a type of Object. But what's happening in this case is that you're calling the function, and it's creating and returning a new object that references `document` at property `0` of that object. That returned Object has *(in its prototype chain)* a set of methods that can be invoked and will usually effect whatever elements you gave it. Oddly enough, in the case of the `.ready()` method, the `document` is actually ignored.

Comment: And that it "references document at property 0 of that object" is determined by syntax or the internal contents of the jQuery() function/object?

Comment: @GuyMontag: Entirely by the internal construct of the function. The actual function itself is very simple. It just calls a different internal constructor function. That's where all the work is done. When you pass it an element *(or a set of elements)*, those elements are added to the object that is constructed, at numeric indices starting at `0`.

Comment: @GuyMontag: You're welcome. If you're interested in seeing how it works, [here's a link](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.1/src/core.js#L4-7) to the code for the `jQuery` function. You'll see that it just returns the result of calling another function, but with the `new` keyword. The `new` makes the other function behave as a constructor. The code for the other *(constructor)* function [is here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.1/src/core.js#L78-186).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(document)` wraps a jQuery instance around the `document` object. (`$` is just an alias for [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).) So the return value of `$(document)` is a jQuery instance, which has a `ready` function on it.

Answer (score 2):

It is a synonym for the jquery() function:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: So that document is the argument to jquery() and ready() acts upon the return type from jquery()?  Is this correct?

Comment: @GuyMontag: document is an argument to jQuery() and ready() is an event handler (a method of jQuery) which accepts a callback function as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`$` is a shortcut for the JQuery object. All methods in the jQuery library are part of the jQuery object.

`$(selector)` is the same as writing 'jQuery(selector)`

Answer (score 1):

the $ before jquery statements is to differentiate between standard javascript and jquery. But other frameworks can use the dollar sign as well, so sometimes you will see jQuery(document) so as not to conflict.  It can also be set to anything really, even $jq, etc.  All it is doing is telling your code to use the framework functions instead of standard javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The $ is a synonym for jQuery and what that does is described here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 1):

`$` is an alias (short-hand) for the variable `jQuery` which is the blanket object that stores all jQuery functions.

`$(document)` is taking your current `window.document` (the `window.` part is often omitted when accessing window properties) and passing it to the jQuery constructor `$()`, and then attaching an event handler to the `ready` event, which executes the anonymous function passed as a callback.

Comment: According to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ jQuery is a function, are you sure it is an object?

Comment: In javascript a function is also an object, a [Function object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

Comment: @GuyMontag everything in javascript is an object.

Answer (score -3):

$ is just a selector for jquery. You're pretty much saying that what follows after "$" is part of the jquery library.

Be careful because some other javascript libraries use that same selector.

Comment: I wouldn't call "$" a "selector."

Comment: I also wouldn't call "$" a constructor.