# How to get an element inside nested divs by class name?

Tags: javascript

A webpage with HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="Parent-div" > </div>
<div class="first-child-div"> </div>
<div class=" second-child-div"> 
    <div class="first-grand-child"> </div>
    <div class="second-grand-child"> </div>
    <div class="Third-grand-child"> 
        <div class="Grand-grand child"> 
           <button  class="Confirm-button">Confirm!</button> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've Tried This code using greasemonkey to remove 
a button from the div with the class named "Grand-grand child"

This is what I did:

```
var targetDiv = document.querySelector("#<Parent-div>. Grand-grand.child");

targetDiv.innerHTML = "Hello world!";
```

The Button wasn't replaced by the Hello world! text, What did I do wrong?

Comment: Note: `class="Grand grand child"` means the element will have 2 classes namely `grand` and `child`. Not one class named *Grand grand child*

Comment: @techfoobar: I'm using greasemonkey to edit some page with the same example above, probably, they are 2 classes

Comment: @j08691: I have tried getelementsbyclassname and querySelector with no result

Comment: If its greasemonkey, you can safely use `document.querySelector` as in PeeHaa's answer.

Comment: @ techfoobar: Tried that already with no luck

Comment: Please post the javascript code your have already tried.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('.Grand.grand.child');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yGv3v/

Comment: Standard disclaimer: IE8+ only.

Comment: var targetDiv = document.querySelector(".Grand.grand.child");


targetDiv[0].innerHTML = "Hello world!"; Didn't work

Comment: @AdelSalah: Well, `targetDiv[0]` is `undefind` because DOM elements don't have a property with name `0`. `.querySelector` returns a DOM element, not a list. And of course you have to make sure that the selector is right. Your example is confusing in this regard.

Comment: @AdelSalah If there will be more elements you want to match you can use `.querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: @Adel: Then your selector might be wrong. Unfortunately it is not possible from your example to determine what the correct selector would be. If the HTML/DOM really is like in your example, then PeeHaa's solution **does work**: http://jsfiddle.net/2NcaN/.

Comment: @PeeHaa How to implement it in my case?

Comment: @FelixKling: Don't understand what do you mean by my selector is wrong. To make it short;  I'm trying to get the sub-sub-div by class name using javascript..

Comment: @Adel: And the div's class names are `Grand`, `grand` and `child`, yes?

Comment: @FelixKling This is the actual class name: id-container-buttons id-confirm-Buttons

Comment: @Adel: So then the selector is `.id-container-buttons.id-confirm-Buttons`. If you want to narrow it even more down: `#<id-of-the-parent> .id-container-buttons.id-confirm-Buttons`.

Comment: @FelixKling: I've already tried your suggestion with no luck:(

Comment: @Adel: Well, we can only help you based on the information you've given us. You said you want to select an element with a specific class and that's what we showed you how to do it. Either you have to provide more information (including an explanation *what* does not work) or better, learn how to debug JavaScript code: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners.

Comment: @FelixKling: I'm going to re-edit my question if that would help me get an answer

Comment: @FelixKling: I did what you advised and debuged the code and that's what I got: ReferenceError: querySelector is not defined

Comment: @Adel: That's strange because `.querySelector` exists since FF 3.5: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector. I don't know enough about Greasemonkey though. All I can say is, follow their tutorials and make sure you are executing the code at the right time.

Comment: @AdelSalah You are supposed to change the id to your actual id and that dot should belong to your class.

Comment: Also your parent div is not the parent.

Comment: @PeeHaa: Your answer is correct. The problem is with GreaseMonkey; The child divs were loaded right after my script, that's why queryselector couldn't find the grand child Div

Comment: @FelixKling: I'm looking for a way to make my script runs after the page fully loaded. Thank you both for help. and sorry for inconvience

Answer (score -2):

You should change `<div class=" Grand grand child">` to `<div class="Grand-grand-child">` and then you can select it with `$('.Grand-grand-child')`.

**Edit**

If you want to use pure JavaScript, then you can select the node element via

```
var grandChildChildNode = document.getElementsByClassName('Third')[0].children[0]
```

This should work in sufficiently modern browsers.

Comment: I can't change it. The HTML code on the page is just like that. I'm using greasemonkey to get the div from that HTML code

Comment: @FelixKling `$` is used in jQquery. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787342/why-does-jquery-have-dollar-signs-everywhere