# What does $ sign mean in jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following code snippet:

```
$Core.box = function($sRequest, $sWidth, $sParams) {
    tb_show('', $.ajaxBox($sRequest, 'width=' + $sWidth + ($sParams ? '&' + $sParams : '')));   
    return false;
};
```

but I'm not understanding what does `$Core` stand for.

What's the meaning of the dollar sign in `$Core` and the other variables?
Why is the function code stored into `$Core.box`?

Comment: Often `$` is used to prefix variables that represent `jQuery` result sets. But your code looks like a php developer wrote some JS code using the `$` prefix for all the variables.

Comment: also answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787342/why-does-jquery-have-dollar-signs-everywhere - jQuery is the jQuery object itself, its a short hand.

Comment: @t.niese:The file containing the above code is not PHP file. It's a .js file

Comment: Without seeing more of the code, it looks like `$Core` is juste a variable which its name starts whith a dollar. Sometimes this notation is used to differentiate "jQuery objects" from others among variables. @LarsAnundskås > you're answering ontly the question title, the question self is different from what you might expect

Comment: The `$` is just a valid character in identifiers (ie. variable names, function names); `a$b = 42;` is perfectly valid in JS, for example ... The `$` has no special meaning to the language.

Comment: valid but generally bad practice :)

Comment: in your code it means nothing...., except for the $.ajaxBox ..

Comment: Might also be related to [this](https://github.com/Munawwar/lithium-ui/wiki/Tutorial-1-Hello-World), where the user tries to access the `Box` package from the `lib/lui/core/Box` directory.

Comment: $ is a shortcut that is used by many JavaScript libraries, not just jQuery.

I would recommend looking at what other libraries are used in the environment/page as there might be a conflict between jQuery and another library that are both trying to use $ as a shortcut.

Comment: @PHPLover I didn't say its is a php file. I just said it looks like it is JavaScript code that was written by a person that is used to write PHP code.

Answer (score 4):

The `$` sign means nothing particular in JavaScript, it is only another valid character to use in variable names.

For example you can call a variable `abc`, `a$b$c`, `hèy` or wathever you like, there's no difference, the only thing that changes is the name of the variable:

```
var abc = 1,
    a$b$c = 2,
    hèy = 3;

console.log(abc, a$b$c, hèy); // 1 2 3
```

**Why the dollar sign then?** **The dollar sign is just a shorter, more convenient name for the `jQuery` function**.

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
// This is usually what a jQuery library does
```

In fact, using the jQuery library it will happen to call `jQuery(...)` several times, and writing `$(...); $(...); $(...);` is much faster than writing `jQuery(...); jQuery(...); jQuery(...);`. You can actually see that typing the following lines in the console of a site that uses jQuery, like Stack Overflow itself, will return a `true` value:

```
$ === jQuery           // true
$.bind === jQuery.bind // true
// and so on...
```

**Then why do users put a `$` at the beginning of variable names?** Since that the common abbreviation for jQuery is the dollar sign, **users tend to name variables created using jQuery with a dollar sign at the beginning**, so it will be easy to know where they come from later in the code, like this:

```
var body = document.body,
    $body = $(document.body); // equivalent to jQuery(document.body);

// Now you know that $body does have all the common jQuery collection properties, but body doesn't
```

Referring to your code: the `$Code` variable is just an object like any other, but it has been probably created using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

`$Core` is just a global variable/object (actually it is the same as `window.$core` in that scope).

`$` is a valid prefix for variable names, although one standard is only to use that prefix for jQuery objects/variables.

`$Core.box = function(){}` is simply assigning a function to a `box` property of that global variable.

*It is likely that function is used by a library or plugin, but without more information about your page and what is included, it is not clear exactly what it is used for* :)