# Why sometimes in Javascript there is the dollar sign ($arg) before function argument?

Tags: javascript

I see sometimes js snippets that are using the $ in front of the argument ($argName).

```
function someName(arg) {
  // some code
  // using arg
}

function someName($arg) {
  // some code
  // using $arg
}
```

In this [js example](https://github.com/giorgioriccardi/script-home.js/blob/master/scrip-home.js#46) it works either way with or without the $ in front of the arguments. Can anyone explaine if it has any use?

Comment: The "$" character is just a character that can be used in an identifier - there's nothing special about it.

Comment: some people use it as a convention to name a jQuery element or an angular builtin service.

Comment: [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) why people only use it for jQuery object drives me mad.

Comment: @epascarello I find it useful as it reminds colleagues that they needn't rewrap the parameter in another `$()` call.  It's a long way from full MS-style Hungarian notation IMHO, and more useful given that JS isn't a strongly typed language.

Comment: @Alnitak JSDoc or any other code documentation seems to fix that problem without making a special case exception for one variable type.

Comment: @epascarello I find it a useful convention.  If you don't, that's fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `$` character is legal in JS identifiers, and is often used simply as a *code convention* to indicate that the passed parameter is already a *jQuery object* (as opposed to a native DOM element).

This serves as a reminder that it's not necessary to re-invoke the jQuery `$(param)` wrapper function on that parameter.

It's also used quite a lot in Angular JS code.

Answer (score 1):

It's sometimes used to reference an object from another library , like JQuery or AngularJS , what you're talking about here looks like `AngularJs`'s  [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) to me

**UPDATE**

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787342/why-does-jquery-have-dollar-signs-everywhere) it might be useful

Comment: the OP was referring to `$varName`, not a bare `$`