# JavaScript / jQuery syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

Hi guys I'm wondering why the $ sign needs to be before the function for the proram to work. I console.log($) and as I thought it is the jQuery selector object. But don't understand why it needs to be there. Please help!!

```
$(function(){
            console.log($, 'testing')
            // when the client clicks SEND
            $('#datasend').click( function() {
                var message = $('#data').val();
                $('#data').val('');
                // tell server to execute 'sendchat' and send along one parameter
                socket.emit('sendchat', message);
            });

            // when the client hits ENTER on their keyboard
            $('#data').keypress(function(e) {
                if(e.which == 13) {
                    $(this).blur();
                    $('#datasend').focus().click();
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: `$(function(...){ ... })` is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function(...){ ... })`...

Comment: Really.... Interesting.. Thanks brotha!

Comment: `$` isn't just for selecting DOM elements, it has many functions depending on what you pass to it. It's a jQuery object constructor though it has other uses.

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10787372/4053389)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript variable naming rules allow "$" sign to be used as a valid variable name. That's why, it acts as a shorthand, and jQuery uses it.

Example:

```
var a = 10;
console.log(a);
```

I can also write

```
var $ = 10;
console.log($);
```

what jQuery does is:

```
jQuery = {};
$ = jQuery;
```

so same jQuery object can be accessed via "$" variable as well. Which acts as a shorthand. If there are two libraries, which tries to use global "$" as their Object, it gives a conflict.

**Now the function we pass inside $(), is nothing but a callback. jQuery wants to know, what code do you want to run on document ready. So, it accepts a function as an argument.**

```
var $ = function( data){
    if(typeof data == "function" ){
        // jquery registers this callback to ready event automatically
    } else {
       // uses the selector, and returns the elements
    }
}

// so this will be registered to ready event
$( function(){
    alert('hi');
});    

// and this will give us the jQuery object with DOM elements
$( "body" );
```

Now, if we pass a selector to jQuery("selector"), jQuery executes that right away.

But if a function is passed as an argument, jQuery registers that function to the ready event automatically. Hence, this callback is executed at ready event.

Comment: This isn't what the question is asking. It's asking why the `$(function(){...})` is there - what it's function is

Comment: @AndrewLi please don't panic. There is always some possibility to edit the answer.

Comment: Well, your edit doesn't make much sense to me. That code block is quite confusing and contradictory. You said it was a callback, run on document ready. Please show that...

Comment: @AndrewLi let's hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Your example doesn't run on document ready. I think you're overcomplicating this. jQuery does different things based on the type of arguments passed to the 'constructor', but the example isn't needed (it actively harms the explanation IMO)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130273/discussion-between-sandeep-and-andrew-li).