# What does $("something") in javascript mean?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the meaning of “$” sign in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150381/what-is-the-meaning-of-sign-in-javascript)

This may be a basic question, but I dare ask.

While I was navigating javascript codes, I found the following.

```
    if(selected_len == all_len) {
        $(":checkbox:checked.node_id_"+d.nodeValue).click();
    }
```

I tried to search what $("") means, but all I found is

"$('hello') --- This is a function declared by many JavaScript frameworks as an extension of document.getElementById."

Could you give more precise explanation, as if you talk to a child :)

Comment: that's probably a jquery selector (http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), but it depends on whatever has been assigned to $ sign

Comment: ...this has been [asked many times before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what+does+dollar+sign+%24+in+javascript+mean). Please do basic research before asking a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$` is a variable name. It means whatever the function assigned to that variable is defined as. (It is not [a good variable name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting).

The contents of it *looks* like a CSS selector, so odds are that it is the common, quick to type, reference to [the jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/category/core/).

Answer (score 4):

In theory it doesn't mean anything more than `foo()` means: it's a function call, where `$` is the name of the function (`$` [is a legal name](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers) for an identifier in Javascript).

In common practice, `$` is the "entry point" for the well-known [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library. There are other libraries that use the name `$` as an entry point, but jQuery is arguably the most widely used.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, it's just a function name and if you use other libraries that are using $ sign, you can use jQuery keyword instead of $ sign.