# getting an error message "Uncaught TypeError: Object .gearImg has no method 'css' "

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I am using jQuery to change the css of some element while hovering on other element and I am getting this error in the Chrome developer tool:
***"Uncaught TypeError: Object .gearImg has no method 'css'"*** 
here is my css code:

```
.gearImg{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 2px;
    right: 10px;
    opacity: 0.5;

}
```

and here is my jquery code:

```
 $('#settings_div').hover(function(){
        $(this).show();
        alert(('.gearImg').css('opacity')); //alerting to find the problem, should show 0.5
    },
    function(){
        $(this).hide();
        ('.gearImg').css('opacity', 0.5);
    });
```

Where is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this please : **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/VGAv8/

`$` missing **--** if you are further curious as to what is `$` read this [What is the meaning of "$" sign in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150381/what-is-the-meaning-of-sign-in-javascript)

Rest should fit the cause `:)`

**code**

```
$('#settings_div').hover(function(){
        $(this).show();
        alert($('.gearImg').css('opacity')); //alerting to find the problem, should show 0.5
    },
    function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $('.gearImg').css('opacity', 0.5);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

How about put `jQuery`/`$` in front of `('.gearImg')` ?
Should be `jQuery('.gearImg')` or `$('.gearImg')`

Answer (score 1):

Missing **$**  in front of the selectors

```
$('#settings_div').hover(function(){
        $(this).show();
        alert($('.gearImg').css('opacity')); //alerting to find the problem, should show 0.5
    },
    function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $('.gearImg').css('opacity', 0.5);
    });
```