# What does $('') mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the meaning of “$” sign in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150381/what-is-the-meaning-of-sign-in-javascript)

I've encountered a code in JavaScript that looks like this:

```
$('svg circle').tipsy({ 
    gravity: 'w', 
    html: true, 
    title: function() {
      return 'Color: '; 
    }
});
```

What does `$('')` mean here?

Comment: It's a function call with a string argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually when you encounter `$()`, that means the developer is using a javascript library, such as jQuery.

The `$` symbol is the namespace for those libraries.  All the functions they define begin with `$.`, such as `$.get()`.  Passing the id of an html tag like this: `$("#myId")` will give you a jQuery object representing that node.

Answer (score 5):

This is from using the [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) library, which is used to standardize JavaScript usage between browsers and make accessing elements and other common tasks much, much easier. It is not a part of JavaScript itself, except insofar as `$` is an acceptable name for a function or variable.

Answer (score 2):

This is the shorted initializing function for [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [zeptojs](http://zeptojs.com/)

```
$("selector").method();
```

It can also mean an shorten for `document.getElementById` if the framework is used:

```
$('myId'); // document.getElementById("myId");
```

---

The plugin [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/) is used witch creates tooltips on hover.