# Removing Jquery Button via dynamically via parentNode

Tags: jquery, button

I have the following script to remove a jquery button:

```
       var elem = $('[symbol="GOOG"][exchange="NASDAQ"][class="remove-button"]') //select the item
       (elem.parentNode).remove();
```

The relevant html is:

```
<div id="GOOG" symbol="GOOG" exchange="NASDAQ" class="stockButton">
        GOOG
        <span symbol="GOOG" exchange="NASDAQ" class="remove-button">
             x
        </span>
</div>
```

However, nothing happens and I'm not sure why? I do something similiar on click elsewhere which works fine. The above two javascript lines I call manually in the code. Thanks.

Comment: May I ask why you don't just use `$("#GOOG").remove();`

Comment: I'm going to be getting rid of the id tag shortly --relic from old code -- so I don't want to reference it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the remove line to this:

```
$(elem).parent().remove();
```

Comment: why do I need another "$", when var elem already equals to a "$(...". This trips me up every time!

Comment: @user1357015 The $ represents the jQuery Function, and is actually a shorthand alias for **jQuery**.  It is typically used as a selector. This link might help you. [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150381/what-is-the-meaning-of-sign-in-javascript)