# Is it ok to remove the $ in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it ok to remove the dollar sign in javascript function? Does it affect to functionality of the whole code inside of it?

from this

```
$(function() {
    // code
});
```

to this

```
(function() {
    // code
});
```

Comment: ... `$` *is* jQuery (by default). Seems like deleting it and reloading the page would have answered your question.

Comment: Would changing `doSomething(1);` to `(1);` affect the functionality?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150381/what-is-the-meaning-of-sign-in-javascript

Comment: Why not just try it and see?

Answer (score 1):

From this question: [What is the meaning of "$" sign in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1150381/682480)

> There's nothing mysterious about the use of "$" in JavaScript. $ is simply a valid JavaScript identifier.
>
> JavaScript allows upper and lower letters, numbers, and $ and _. The $ was intended to be used for machine-generated variables (such as $0001).
>
> Prototype, jQuery, and most javascript libraries use the $ as the primary base object (or function). Most of them also have a way to relinquish the $ so that it can be used with another library that uses it. In that case you use "jQuery" instead of "$". In fact, "$" is just a shortcut for "jQuery".

and

> The `$` represents the [jQuery Function](http://docs.jquery.com/Core), and is actually a shorthand alias for `jQuery`. (Unlike in most languages, the `$` symbol is not reserved, and may be used as a variable name.) It is typically used as a selector (i.e. a function that returns a set of elements found in the DOM).

Answer (score 0):

Doing

```
$(function() {
    // code
});
```

is just calling the jQuery function. It's just function, imagine something like this:

```
function $(callback){
    //do many things

    //call the callback
    callback();
}
```

Indeed it's defined like this:

```
function( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    // Need init if jQuery is called (just allow error to be thrown if not included)
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
}
```