# what does JQuery's "$" symbol mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

so plz forgive me for my silly question,
I know "$" is a shortcut for jQuery, but I've been seen some code like:

```
  var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
  $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
  $title = $xml.find( "title" );
```

so my questions are:

1. How come there is no "var" prefix for xmlDoc? shouldn't it be:

   var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml )?

2.what does the "$" in $xml stands for? if xml is a variable, shouldn't it be:

```
var xml = $( xmlDoc )?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of "$" sign in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150381/what-is-the-meaning-of-sign-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. no "var" prefix for xmlDoc is valid, it is using short syntax of variable declaration (see `,`). Even if there were no `,` it'll declare a global javascript variable.
2. "$" in $xml changes nothing, `$xml` is a valid variable name just like other variable names.

Answer (score 0):

There might be other libraries also using jQuery shortcut **$**.
This link might help better understand shortcut for jQuery:

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/