# What is this : sign after a variable JS syntax?

Tags: javascript, syntax, svelte, labeled-statements

I came across the following valid syntax in JS when looking at `svelte` library:

```
$: doubled = 6 * 2;
```

At first, I thought it was specific for the library, **but it works on the Chrome console**. What is this syntax?

It can be anything:

```
name: something = 6 * 2;
```

Comment: It's just variable/property name. `doubled` is probably a typescript interface or a class

Comment: `$` is valid character in any JavaScript identifier. Without seeing more context for that code, it looks like a labelled statement to me.

Comment: @SudhirOjha you are wrong :) jQuery **is** JavaScript.

Comment: @Pointy You can never have enough jQuery.

Comment: This is so interesting, i can't find anything about it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150381/what-is-the-meaning-of-sign-in-javascript

Comment: just to add to @Pointy, it's like `label: x = 1 + 1;`

Comment: It works in Chrome console 
because it's a valid [labeled statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). From [their github](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/tree/master/src) it looks like they are using typescript. So, it's unlikely that this is labeled statement

Comment: It actually works in Vanilla JS! This is ridiculous, I completely expected it to throw a syntax error.

Comment: @adiga I understand, possibly incorrectly, that TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript syntax

Comment: @Pointy All javascript is valid typescript** (Conditions apply: `var a = "";
a = 1;` will throw an error). But, it does look like labeled statement after all https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/4541d587987bb99d91754d24660e59cec5866e44/site/content/tutorial/02-reactivity/02-reactive-declarations/text.md#L14

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Any JavaScript statement (kind-of except function declarations) can be preceded by a label:

```
foo: var x = 0;
```

What you've got there is something like that:

```
$: doubled = 6 * 2;
```

In your statement, "$" is the label.

There's not much point to labelled statements because there's no `goto` in JavaScript. Both `break` and `continue` can include a label of an enclosing loop to indicate how many "layers" should be involved.

```
wholeLoop:
for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
    if (matrix[i][j] == null)
      // Oh no! This is terrible
      break wholeLoop;
  }
}
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-labelled-statements)

---

All the above is pretty much correct, but apparently Svelte applies its own build-time preprocessor to component source code and translates that into the actual JavaScript sent to the browser. This use of the label syntax is "hijacked" by them to mean something; see Quentin's answer.

Comment: Not enough jQuery.

Comment: @LogicalBranch funny thing is I'm like the last jQuery user on earth I sometimes think.

Comment: I still use various versions of jQuery in production environments, mainly for safety and browser support. It's probably the greatest JS library to exist.

Comment: I think the saddest thing about jQuery is when people attack you for using it then make out out to be some kind of demon for wanting good browser support.

Comment: Yea I mean, it just gets rid of a bunch of unnecessary headaches, and so long as it's not abused I don't have a problem with it. (jQueryUI I don't like, however, but that's mostly a matter of design opinion.)

Comment: In the beginning jQuery UI was very promising, then they added those horrific themes/add ons.

Answer (score 20):

This is label in JavaScript.

The interesting point here is how Svelte is using this to bind variables to other variables. [Here's a portion of a video where Rich Harris explains this](https://youtu.be/AdNJ3fydeao?t=863).

Essentially, in Svelte, **`$:`** means **re-run whenever these values change**

If we look a the example in Svelte's [Reactive declarations example](https://svelte.dev/examples#reactive-declarations),

```
<script>
    let count = 1;

    // the `$:` means 're-run whenever these values change'
    $: doubled = count * 2;
    $: quadrupled = doubled * 2;

    function handleClick() {
        count += 1;
    }
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
    Count: {count}
</button>

<p>{count} * 2 = {doubled}</p>
<p>{doubled} * 2 = {quadrupled}</p>
```

The variables `doubled` and `quadrupled` have `$` label. So, they'll be computed again when `count` or `doubled` changes respectively.

If you take a look at the compiled code, you can see

```
let doubled, quadrupled;
$$self.$$.update = ($$dirty = { count: 1, doubled: 1 }) => {
    if ($$dirty.count) { $$invalidate('doubled', doubled = count * 2); }
    if ($$dirty.doubled) { $$invalidate('quadrupled', quadrupled = doubled * 2); }
};
```

So, each time the update happens, there is a dirty check for those variables and update.

In conclusion. `$:` in Svelte doesn't have anything to do with JavaScript label. It's a directive for Svelte compiler to have the code for updating those variables. `$:` is of course valid syntax but outside the context of Svelte, it doesn't do what it does in Svelte. It's the compilation that does the magic ;)

Answer (score 12):

In JavaScript, it is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) and is designed to be used when using `break` and `continue` in conjunction with nested loops (so you can pick which loop you are breaking or continuing from).

Svelte appears to use some kind of hack to give it alternative meaning. See [the tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-declarations):

> Svelte automatically updates the DOM when your component's state
>   changes. Often, some parts of a component's state need to be computed
>   from other parts (such as a fullname derived from a firstname and a
>   lastname), and recomputed whenever they change.
>
> For these, we have reactive declarations. They look like this:
>
> ```
> let count = 0;
> $: doubled = count * 2;
> ```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, I just error this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable doubled"

Answer (score 4):

To add more detail to the answers already provided:

- It essentially defines a '[destiny operator](https://paulstovell.com/reactive-programming/)' in Svelte (a destiny operator is a general concept of 'reactive programming')
- A destiny operator ensures a variable is updated whenever values that it's computed from are changed)

Rich Harris (the creator of Svelte) wrote an article a while back about use of the destiny operator, that explains the concept well (although at the time he didn't specifically suggest using `$`:

https://gist.github.com/Rich-Harris/aa3dc83d3d8a4e572d9be11aedc8c238

Answer (score 1):

For Svelte.js specifically, that `$:` [Marks A Statement as 'reactive'](https://svelte.dev/docs#3_$_marks_a_statement_as_reactive) meaning that it will update based on the variables that follow - as others have also written that's a label in javascript, but in svelte it has special meaning.