# JavaScript: What is this expression good for? Ajax maybe?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this code here:

```js
shortenURL('#(campaign.id)', url, function(shortenedURL) {
  if (youtubeID && youtubeID != "") {
    shortenedURL = clientUrl
  }
  $("#textCopiedModal #sharer-link").attr("href", 'javascript:openFacebook("' + shortenedURL + '")')
  $("#textCopiedModal #sharer-link #social-network-name").text('Facebook')
  $('#textCopiedModal').modal()
})
```

And I do not know what is this mean: `$("#textCopiedModal #sharer-link")`

It is clearly a JavaScript code. But what specific is it more? Some kind of AJAX expression?

Comment: It's a selector to select the element with the id of `sharer-link` inside of the element witht the id of `textCopiedModal` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Comment: jQuery with a selector.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of "$" sign in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150381/what-is-the-meaning-of-sign-in-javascript)

Comment: It's also not a great selector since '#' points to an ID which is meant to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

It's a jQuery code to select the DOM element with Id "sharer-link", which is inside the element with Id "textCopiedModal".