# why some people write a function like $(function( $ )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that code like `$(function( $ )` does not make any sense, but I have find this sort of code at various places including [todomvc](http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/backbone/js/views/app.js).

There is a reason writing functions like `jQuery(function( $ )` to resolve any potential conflict of `$` used by any other library, but not `$function($)`.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14869172/601179) is what you're asking about?

Comment: I don't understand which one your are talking about - `$(function(){})` or `(function($){})(jQuery)`?

Comment: You should edit your question to what is that real bothers you. Is it the `$` before the function or the `$` parameter. please explain.

Comment: Not sure I understand what are you asking about. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371539/why-define-anonymous-function-and-pass-it-jquery-as-the-argument

Comment: The fact you didn't get an answer to the question why is it good for, means it's good for nothing. IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason to use

```
$(function($))...
```

If you use the dollar sign in the beginning of the line you rely on that it's a jQuery object, so if you pass the jQuery object later on as a parameter to avoid conflicts, why didn't you use it on the first place? It's too later for that now...

The right way to use it is with:

```
(function($){ // The dollar variable is a parameter.
   $(function(){ // You use the $ variable only inside the function.
   });
})(jQuery); // jQuery is passed as a parameter.

$.somePrototypeFunctionHere(); // Here the dollar variable can be something else.
```

Comment: Thats my point of view as well. I was confused about it as i have seen the code in many places including http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/backbone/#/.

Comment: @Asif, I can't see that pattern there, anyway as I wrote, it doesn't make sense, don't use other guys mistakes. The fact a lot of people write bad code doesn't mean we need to mock them. EOF.

Comment: You can find the the use here... and I dont think they used just by mistake. they have good patterns implemented there. http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/backbone/js/views/app.js.

Comment: @RabNawaz, O.K. **1.** I can't find there where they are sending the parameter that `$` should be. **2.** Still doesn't make sense.

Comment: @gdoron my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14869165/1338292) discusses the inner workings of the `$` passing in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 3):

**It's useless**

This form is not useful at all:

```
$(function($) {
});
```

It will work ONLY if there are no other libraries that could override `$` (e.g. prototype).

**How it could be useful**

Since jQuery passes itself as the first argument to the DOM ready event handler function, this is how you could make good use of it:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // this === document
    // $ === jQuery
});
```

The [proof](http://jsbin.com/izexun/1/) of this behaviour can also be found in [the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L385):

```
readyList.resolveWith( document, [ jQuery ] );
```

It maps `this` to `document` and the first argument to your ready function to `jQuery`. The reason why the code looks a bit non-obvious is because the ready event is handled using `Deferred`.

**The equivalent**

The somewhat equivalent notation is this:

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
  }
}(jQuery));
```

This would be preferred if you're doing more things outside of the ready handler, which actually happens more often than you think.

Comment: @gdoron Yeah, it just gives a false sense of security that it will reference the right symbol. Oh well, whatever floats their boat.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you can initialize jQuery scripts for DOM when it is ready. The popular methods are:

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

And the short hand for the same is:

```
$(function(){});
```

---

#### Update #1: The `$()` vs. `jQuery()` fight!

For the reason of asking `jQuery` vs. `$`, the reason is most Libraries use `$` as a shorter way to access functions within the libraries. Say, MooTools and Prototype JS. So, to avoid conflict, they might replace `$` with `jQuery`.

jQuery has a function called [`jQuery.noConflict();`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) which relinquishs jQuery's control of the `$` variable making `$` not work with jQuery. Hope this clears your problem.

In the Prototype.JS [documentation](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar/), the `$` symbol returns the element in the document with matching ID; otherwise returns the passed element.

Also, the `$` function is the cornerstone of Prototype. Not only does it provide a handy alias for `document.getElementById`, it also lets you pass indifferently IDs (strings) or DOM node references to your functions.

---

#### Update #2: For your question on `$` as a parameter...

No one uses:

```
$(function($){})
```

It is either

```
(function($){})(jQuery);
```

or

```
$(function(){});
```

Please check. :)

Comment: The same can achieved by $(function(){}, but my question is about the $ as an argument.

Comment: @Asif Added your query. See the answer. :)

Comment: I know the reason for $(function(){}); but my question is about why some people use $(function($){}); as aperantly it does not make sense.

Comment: @Asif No one uses `$(function($){})`. It is either `(function($){})(jQuery)` or `$(function(){});`. Please check. :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar Whether nobody uses it is something else altogether; that doesn't mean it won't work.

Comment: @PraveenKumar My [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14869165/1338292) discusses the inner workings of `$(function($) { ... });`.

Answer (score 1):

Most people that writes `$(function(){})` do it because they are users. i.e. They have chosen to use jquery and not any conflicting libraries. Thus it's safe to use it.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. Where is the dollar parameter?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function( $ )
```

is shorthand for

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

and you are right:  `Jquery(function( $ )` is used  in the event of possible conflicts with jquery and other js libraries

Comment: The same can achieved by $(function(){}, but my question is about the $ as an argument.

Comment: It's shorthand for `$(document).ready(function($) {` actually.

Answer (score 1):

yes because as you might know prototype also use `$` so here`jQuery` is become great which allows us to use jQuery even if $ is preserved by some other lib.

[**check Here**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

[**Using jQuery with Other Libraries**](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)

Answer (score 0):

This is the better way to resolve any potential conflict of `$`:

```
(function($){
   $(function(){
      // all the code stuff here....
   });
})(jQuery);
```

Your edit:
`My question is actually misunderstood by many giving answers. I want to know about the dollar as an argument in the function.`

This is just for securing the `$` sign which is shorthand for `jQuery` and there are many other libraries which also uses the `$` sign, so there are frequent chances to get in trouble with this.

read here from the docs:

> it's a best practice to pass jQuery to an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) that maps it to the dollar sign so it can't be overwritten by another library in the scope of its execution.

```
(function($) {
     // all other things    
})(jQuery);
```

> Now within that closure, we can use the dollar sign in place of jQuery as much as we like.

**More [here to read](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)**

Comment: The code from the question is different from what you have written here.

Comment: It was just an explanation about passing `$` in the function arg, how to secure the `$` against conflict with other libs `$` sign and correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() { 
  // Do your code here...
});
```

ensures that the document and scripts are fully downloaded.

```
(function($){ 
  // Do your code here...
})(jQuery);
```

enables to use $ symbol in the function without conflicts with other libraries which gives a different meaning to $ symbol.

So you can use both the above together.

```
(function($){ 
   $(function() { 
      // Do your code here... 
   }); 
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; the code shown is different from what you have written in any of your code samples.

Answer (score 0):

From [ready() | jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

**Aliasing the jQuery Namespace**

When using another JavaScript library, we may wish to call `$.noConflict()` to avoid namespace difficulties. When this function is called, the `$` shortcut is no longer available, forcing us to write `jQuery` each time we would normally write `$`. However, the handler passed to the `.ready()` method can take an argument, which is passed the global `jQuery` object. This means we can rename the object within the context of our `.ready()` handler without affecting other code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Code using $ as usual goes here.
});
```

This are other ways to specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded. It can be done in three ways in jQuery -

All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){})

jQuery().ready(function($){}) //(this is not recommended)

jQuery(function($){})
```

Another way to resolver conflicts would be -

```
(function($) { /* some code that uses $ */ })(jQuery)
```

You may like to read [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).

Comment: Right, I did not see the link he provided.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Passing `JQuery` object makes it local scoped (to the module as far as I understand). It is used as a performance enhancement.

```
(function($) {
  // Code in here
})(jQuery);
```