# What is the significance of this function definition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I understand how to define functions like this:

```
function myfunc(x,y,z) {
   alert("Just an example " + x + y + z)
}
```

But not this:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        (function ($) {
        $.fn.idle = function (x, y, z) {
            alert("Just an example " + x + y + z)
    }(jQuery));
    </script>
```

The above is a part of a library I'm using, but I simply can't understand the `$.fn.idle` bit.

What is it doing? It's defining a function called 'idle', somehow, but what about the `$.fn`? And what about the `(function ($) {` part? Again, I understand `$(document).ready(function() {` but `(function ($) {` is completely alien. Is it a short hand?

And what is the significance of the `(jQuery));` at the bottom?

Comment: That's just how you define jQuery plug-ins.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why define anonymous function and pass it jQuery as the argument?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10371539/1420197)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716069/how-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-work-function-window-undefined

Comment: This is a very common pattern for defining plugins. Several of the concepts you've asked about in your question are probably answered in separate questions because they are separate concepts.

Comment: Actually it's a syntax error, you forgot `};`

Comment: Neither of the duplicates is actually addressing `$.fn.` or simply property/method definition in general

Comment: I don't think there is a single question that addresses both at the same time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An [immediately invoked function expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) which aliases `jQuery` to `$` inside its scope:

```
(function($) {}(jQuery));
```

It creates and executes a function immediately. This way you can use `$` inside the function to reference jQuery regardless of what the global `$` references to. Useful for pages using `jQuery.noConflict()`. Also the variables declared inside that IIFE don't leak to the global scope.

---

As for the other part of the question, `$.fn === jQuery.prototype`. So by adding a method to the jQuery prototype, you may call it on any jQuery object. E.g.:

```
$.fn.doSomething = function(){}; //add a method to the jQuery prototype
$('selector').doSomething(); //then you may call it on any jQuery object
```

More on [jQuery plugin authoring](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).

Comment: Why do they reference the prototype instead of making us use it ?

Comment: Oh just noticed that my websockets are broken on Nightly. @Virus721 Sorry not sure what you meant. `jQuery.fn` is just a shortcut (reference) to `jQuery.prototype`, "Write less, do more" as they say. You may use either of these. `=]`

Comment: @Virus721 because fn is 7 characters shorter than prototype? i don't know.

Comment: Other libraries such as Moment.js also use `fn` as shortcut for `prototype`, too.

Comment: I imagine making such a shortcut can cut down on the minified size of the library and it's plugins quite a bit with how often it's used.

Comment: Before reading your answer i was thinking that fn was an object that was iterated over using for(var in) to copy every method from it into the newly created jQuery object, but i thought it was done manually, i havn't thought about it being the prototype.

Comment: Though most of the jQuery methods are defined like `$.fn = $.prototype = {/*methods*/}` ([source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/302f222df03d2c65f409b11b7fa65dba5400180f/src/core.js#L76)) or `$.fn.extend({/*methods*/})`, I agree that it should cut down some bytes as @KevinB said. `=]`

Answer (score 1):

This is known as an IIFE - Immediately Invoked Function Expression.

```
(function ($) {
    // inside stuff
}(jQuery));
```

`jQuery` is imported to the function body as `$`, and the function is run immediately.

```
// inside stuff

$.fn.idle = function (x, y, z) {
    alert("Just an example " + x + y + z)
} // added in missing parentheses
```

`$.fn` is equivalent to `jQuery.fn` and `jQuery.fn.idle` is simply a property on `jQuery.fn` that points to a function.

Another interesting point, is that `jQuery.fn` is an alias for `jQuery.prototype`, i.e. they are the same thing.

A lot of aliases here makes the code a bit more complicated than it actually is.

This is a common structure you will see for adding plugins/mixins to a library.

Hope, I cut this up for you well.

Answer (score 1):

Adding functions to `$.fn` makes them available for use on jQuery objects.

```
$.fn.alertTitle = function() { alert( $(this).attr('title') ); };
$('#foo').alertTitle();
```

Answer (score 1):

this is assigning a function to a variable:

```
var test = function () { alert('testing'); }
test(); // will alert testing
```

A function assigned to a variable is also called an 'anonymous function' because it does not have a name, is is often used to pass a function as a parameter to another function.

In javascript, a variable may start with a `$`, and this is used by jQuery. jQuery is an object, which has properties, one of which is called `fn`. this property can also have properties, in this case `idle`.

so `$.fn.idle = function () {};` comes down to this:

```
$ = {
    fn: {
        idle: function () {}
    }
};
```

This is also referred to as 'namespacing' although that can have other nuances aswell.
Also be aware that the you can only assign properties to existing objects:

```
var myVar = {};
myVar.test.foo = {}; // results in error because myVar.test is undefined
myVar.test = {
    foo: {}
}; // this is correct
```