# Passing $ as a function argument (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I came across a code like this:

```
function doSomething($, $variable){
  ...
}



(function ($){

  $(function () {
   doSomething ($, $('.div'));
  });

}(jQuery));
```

Is it the same as defining `doSomething()` inside of jQuery and removing the `$`?

Thanks

Comment: yes, it looks like some people overencapsulate stuff

Comment: `$` is just like any other variable: you can pass it as function parameter or make it a global variable in the outer scope.

Comment: you can refer to this post for clear understanding about it [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371539/why-define-an-anonymous-function-and-pass-it-jquery-as-the-argument). It explain quite  well about the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it the same as defining `doSomething()` inside of `jQuery` and removing the `$`?

If you mean, is it the same as:

```
(function ($){

  $(function () {
    function doSomething($, $variable){
    }
    doSomething($('.div'));
  });

}(jQuery));
```

...then no, because in the version in your question, `doSomething` is apparently global, whereas if you define it within another function, it isn't.

The structure at the end of your question is meant to protect against `noConflict` mode where `$` does not equal `jQuery`, by creating a function and calling it, passing in `jQuery` and accepting it as an argument named `$`. It may be that the author was unaware of the fact that jQuery passes a reference to itself into the ready callback, so that code could more simply be:

```
function doSomething($, $variable){
  ...
}

jQuery(function($) {
   doSomething ($, $('.div'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The first function is an IIFE that closes over `$` and sets the value to  `jQuery`. It's commonly used to avoid `$` being overwritten by other code elsewhere.

Inside that IIFE, `$` will always be `jQuery`, but outside the IIFE, it might not be.

The inner function `$(function () {..` is just a DOM ready handler, that waits for the document to load before executing code inside it.

The `doSomething` function is defined outside the IIFE, and doesn't have access to the arguments from the IIFE, so `$` could be undefined or something other than jQuery in that scope, hence the author decided to pass `$` as an argument to `doSomething($, $variable)`, it's a little hard to read because both the passed value, and the argument have the same name.