# When to use this in javascript OO?

Tags: javascript, oop, scope

In Javascript OO, when should I use the `this` keyword?

Also, if I want to call a method of a class from another method of the same class, should I use `this` or just the name of the function? E.g is this correct?

```
function Foo()
{
   this.bar= function()
   {
      alert('bar');
   }

   this.baz= function()
   {
     this.bar(); //should I use this.bar() or just bar()?
   }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use just `bar()` because `this` is never implicit in JavaScript (since it's not really a proper object-oriented language.) `bar()` would first look for a variable defined as `bar` in the function `this.baz`, then it would look for a variable defined as `bar` in the function `Foo` and finally it would look in the global scope, and failing that it would throw an error.

Comment: It's important to learn the JavaScript prototype system, so it's a great question to ask. But if I were going to do a large OO program in JavaScript, I'd use Joose.js or Js.Class.

Comment: There are some downvote trolls that vote down if they don't agree, or think silly, what is just wrong by the S.O. definition of downvote =\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When it comes to "object-oriented" JavaScript, here's a nice guide Mark Dickinson here on SO linked to: [Private Members in JavaScript](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html). It does go into detail about some other stuff you don't really need now, but once you understand how JavaScript works, you'll see that it's quite different from your ordinary object-oriented language when it comes to things like what `this` really means.

I'd say that in your case, you should definitely use `this`, but maybe your functions should be in the `prototype` part of your "class" (this avoids redefining the function every time a new instance is created.)

Comment: I made a simple template for classes that seems to be very similar to what Douglas Crawford has in his article (that I linked.) If looking at code helps, you could always look at that: http://blixt.org/js/classes.js (raw file) http://blixt.org/js#project/js-classes (with syntax highlight)

Comment: what do you mean by the 'prototype part of the class'?

Comment: Functions have a `prototype` property that is used as the prototype for objects created when calling the function with the `new` keyword. If you set `Foo.prototype.bar = function () {...};`, then all objects created with `new Foo()` will have a `bar` property that references the `Foo.prototype.bar` function.

Answer (score 1):

I have found [3 Ways to define a javascript class](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular instance, it's best to use a self-referencing variable in the place of `this` to prevent confusion and headaches inside functions.

```
function Foo()
{
   var self = this;

   this.bar= function()
   {
      alert('bar');
   }

   this.baz= function()
   {
     self.bar();
   }
}
```

The reason for it is because since everything in javascript is an object, the `this` keyword inside a function refers to the parent function.  By defining a variable at a certain scope, your guaranteed that variable will maintain its scope.

Comment: You do it so the scope is obvious. A lot of people use "that" instead of "self."

Comment: Note that by doing so, you're removing the possibility to rebind the function, i.e. `fooInstance.baz.call(barInstance);`

Comment: @tj111: You said, "In your example, the call to this.bar() is referring to Foo.baz.bar, not Foo.bar".  This is not true.  If you create an instance of Foo and call baz then the context for baz is your Foo instance.  Check it out: http://jsbin.com/onida/edit

Comment: You certainly need the self-reference in nested functions or where the function will be called in a different context - event handlers and deferred calls, for example. I try to avoid using it globally though.

Answer (score 0):

Just to stress and empathize previous answer of @tj111 I suggest you to read [this](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Functional_Javascript). To better understand function scoping.

Answer (score 0):

The correct version is the one that doesn't give an error when you try to call the function. If you omit `this` you will get a `ReferenceError` exception.

Answer (score 0):

In another post about 'function aliasing' in JavaScript, I explained in detail, with examples, how 'this' works in JavaScript. I think it may be useful to you.

Please check: [JavaScript function aliasing doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007340/javascript-function-aliasing-doesnt-seem-to-work/1162192#1162192)